# ¿Qué es una NullReferenceException y cómo solucionarla?

Tags: c#, .net, excepciones

En numerosas ocasiones se recibe una `NullReferenceException`, siendo una de las excepciones que más preguntas suscita. ¿Qué significa `NullReferenceException` y cómo se puede solucionar?

<sub>Para el `NullReferenceException` en VB.NET, véase [NullReferenceException: ¿Qué es y cómo puedo solucionarla?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/76861/15301)</sub>

Comment: asociación: https://stackoverflow.com/q/4660142

Answer (score 62, accepted):

## ¿Cuál es la causa?

### Esencialmente

Estás intentando utilizar algún objeto que es `null` (o `Nothing` en VB.NET). Esto significa que, o lo has inicializado a `null`, o en ningun momento lo inicializaste.

`null` es un valor como los demás,y se pasa de la misma manera. Si tienes `null` *en el* método "A", puede ser que el método "B" haya pasado un `null` *al* método "A".

El resto de esta respuesta va a entrar en más detalle y mostrar errores que muchos programadores cometen habitualmente y que pueden llevar a obtener una `NullReferenceException`.

### Más específicamente

Cuando el motor de tiempo de ejecución (*runtime*) lanza una `NullReferenceException` **siempre** significa lo mismo: estás intentando usar una referencia. Esta referencia no se ha inicializado (o fue inicializada *en algún momento* , pero *ya* no está inicializada).

Esto significa que la referencia es `null`, y no se puede acceder a los miembros de una referencia si ésta es `null`. Este es el caso mas simple:

```
string variable = null;
variable.ToUpper();
```

Este código lanzará una `NullReferenceException` en la segunda línea, ya que no se puede llamar al método de instancia `ToUpper()` en una referencia de `string` que apunta a `null`.

## Depuración

¿Cómo encuentro el origen de una excepción `NullReferenceException`? Además de estudiando la excepción en si, que será lanzada en el lugar exacto en el que ocurre, se deben aplicar las reglas generales de depuración en Visual Studio: poner puntos de ruptura (*breakpoints*) estratégicamente e [inspeccionar las variables](https://msdn.microsoft.com/es-es/library/esta7c62.aspx), bien poniendo el cursor del ratón encima de sus nombres, abriendo una ventanta de Inspección (Rápida) o bien usando los paneles de depuración existentes como Variables locales y Automático.

Si quieres encontrar dónde la referencia está o no asignada, pulsa con el botón derecho en su nombre y elige "Encontrar todas las referencias". A continuación puedes poner un punto de ruptura en todas las localizaciones encontradas y ejecutar de nuevo el programa en depuración. Cada vez que el depurador pare la ejecución en ese punto, necesitarás determinar si esperabas que la referencia en ese punto no fuera nula, inspeccionando la variable y verificando que apunta a una instancia cuando debería.

Siguiendo el flujo del programa de esta manera, podrás encontrar la localización donde la instancia no debería ser nula, y por qué no ha sido inicializada como debería.

## Ejemplos

Algunos escenarios comunes donde podemos encontrar esta excepción:

#### Genéricos

```
ref1.ref2.ref3.miembro
```

Si ref1 o ref2 o ref3 son `null`, entonces obtendrás una `NullReferenceException`. Si quieres resolver este problema, entonces deberás encontrar cuál de ellas es `null` reescribiendo la expresión a su equivalente más sencillo:

```
var r1 = ref1;
var r2 = r1.ref2;
var r3 = r2.ref3;
r3.miembro
```

Por ejemplo, en `HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.Name`, el `HttpContext.Current` podría ser `null`, o la propiedad `User` podría ser `null`, o la propiedad `Identity` podría ser `null`.

#### Instancias de clase

Cuando se crea cualquier variable de tipo de referencia (de clase), por defecto esta es inicializada a `null`.

```
public class Libro {
    public string Titulo { get; set; }
}
public class Ejemplo {
    public void Prueba() {
        Libro b1;
        string titulo = b1.Titulo;  // Nunca has inicializado la variable b1
                                    // asi que no hay ningun libro del que obtener el título
    }
}
```

Las variables de Clase deben o ser inicializadas o asignadas con una instancia de la misma clase ya inicializada. La inicialización se consigue utilizando la palabra clave `new`.

```
Libro b1 = new Libro();
```

#### Indirecta

```
public class Persona {
    public int Edad { get; set; }
}
public class Libro {
    public Persona Autor { get; set; }
}
public class Ejemplo {
    public void Prueba() {
        Libro b1 = new Libro();
        int edadAutor = b1.Autor.Edad; // La propiedad Autor nunca ha sido inicializada
                                       // asi que no existe ninguna Persona de la que obtener su edad.
    }
}
```

Si quieres evitar la referencia nula del hijo (Persona), podrías inicializarla en el constructor del padre (Libro).

Esto mismo aplica a los inicializadores de objetos anidados:

```
Libro b1 = new Libro { Autor = { Edad = 45 } };
```

Aunque en este ejemplo se usa la palabra clave `new`, ésta solo crea una nueva instancia de `Libro`, pero no una nueva instancia de `Persona`, así que la propiedad `Autor` sigue siendo `null`.

#### Arrays

```
int[] numeros = null;
int n = numeros[0]; // numeros es null. No pueden existir los indices.
```

#### Elementos de un Array

```
Persona[] gente = new Persona[5];
gente[0].Edad = 20 // gente[0] es null. El array ha sido asignado en memoria pero no inicializado
                   // No existe ninguna persona para la que asignar la edad.
```

#### Arrays Irregulares (*Jagged Arrays*)

```
long[][] array = new long[1][];
array[0][0] = 3; // es null porque sólo la primera dimensión ha sido inicializada.
                 // Se debe usar array[0] = new long[2]; primero.
```

#### Colecciones/Listas/Diccionarios

```
Dictionary<string, int> edadesPorNombres = null;
int age = edadesPorNombres["Bob"]; // edadesPorNombres is null.
                                   // No existe ningún Diccionario donde realizar la búsqueda.
```

#### Variables de rango (Indirectas/Diferidas)

```
public class Persona {
    public string Nombre { get; set; }
}
var gente = new List<Persona>();
gente.Add(null);
var nombres = from p in gente select p.Nombre;
string primerNombre = nombres.First(); // La Excepción se lanza aquí, pero en realidad ha ocurrido
                                       // en la línea anterior.  "p" es null porque el primer
                                       // elemento que añadimos a la lista es null
```

#### Eventos

```
public class Demo
{
    public event EventHandler EstadoCambiado;

    protected virtual void OnEstadoCambiado(EventArgs e)
    {        
        EstadoCambiado(this, e); // La excepción es lanzada aquí
                                 // si no existe ningún manejador de eventos acoplado 
                                 // al evento EstadoCambiado
    }
}
```

#### Nombres que no siguen las convenciones:

Si hubieras nombrado los campos de manera diferente a las variables locales, podrías haber notado que nunca inicializaste el campo.

```
public class Form1 {
    private Cliente cliente;

    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e) {
        Cliente cliente = new Cliente();
        cliente.Nombre = "Juan";
    }

    private void Button_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) {
        MessageBox.Show(cliente.Nombre);
    }
}
```

Esto se puede solucionar siguiendo la convención de que a los campos se les añade una barra baja (`_`) antes del nombre:

```
private Cliente _cliente;
```

#### Ciclo de vida de una página ASP.NET:

```
public partial class EdicionProblemas : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    protected ProblemaTest miProblema;

    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (!IsPostBack)
        {
            // Solo se llama en la primera carga, no cuando se pulsa el botón
            miProblema= new ProblemaTest(); 
        }
    }

    protected void BotonGuardar_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        myProblema.Entrada = "¡NullReferenceException aqui!";
    }
}
```

#### Valores de Sesión de ASP.NET

```
// si el valor de sesión "Nombre" no ha sido añadido todavía,
// entonces esta línea lanzará una NullReferenceException
string nombre = Session["Nombre"].ToString();
```

#### ASP.NET MVC View Models vacíos

Si la excepción ocurre cuando se referencia una propiedad de `@Modelo` en una vista de ASP.NET MVC, necesitas entender que el `Modelo` se inicializa en tu método `action`, cuando devuelves(`return`) una vista. Cuando devuelves un modelo vacío (o una propiedad del modelo) desde tu controlador, la excepción es lanzada cuando la vista accede a él:

```
// Controlador
public class Restaurante:Controller
{
    public ActionResult Buscar()
    {
         return View();  // Olvidaste proporcionar un modelo aqui.
    }
}

// Razor view 
@foreach (var restauranteBuscar in Model.BuscarRestaurante)  // Se lanza la excepción.
{
}

<p>@Model.algunaPropiedad</p> <!-- tambien se lanza la excepción -->
```

#### Orden de creación de controles y eventos en WPF

Los controles WPF son creados durante la llamada a `InitializeComponent` en el orden en el que aparecen en el árbol visual.  Una excepción `NullReferenceException` puede producirse en el caso de que controles creados antes con manejadores de eventos, etc. , que se disparan durante `InitializeComponent`, referencien controles creados después.

Por ejemplo:

```
<Grid>
    <!-- Combobox se declara primero -->
    <ComboBox Name="comboBox1" 
              Margin="10"
              SelectedIndex="0" 
              SelectionChanged="comboBox1_SelectionChanged">
        <ComboBoxItem Content="Elemento 1" />
        <ComboBoxItem Content="Elemento 2" />
        <ComboBoxItem Content="Elemento 3" />
    </ComboBox>

    <!-- Label declarado después -->
    <Label Name="label1" 
           Content="Etiqueta"
           Margin="10" />
</Grid>
```

Aqui `comboBox1` es creado antes que `label1`. Si el evento `comboBox1_SelectionChanged` intenta referenciar a `label1`, éste todavía no ha sido creado.

```
private void comboBox1_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
{
    label1.Content = comboBox1.SelectedIndex.ToString(); // ¡¡NullReference aquí!!
}
```

Cambiando el orden de las declaraciones en el XAML (por ejemplo, poniendo `label1` antes que `comboBox1`, ignorando los problemas de la filosofía de diseño), al menos resolvería la `NullReferenceException` en este caso.

#### Cast con `as`

```
var miCosa = unObjeto as Cosa;
```

Esto no lanzaría una InvalidCastException, sino que devolvería `null` cuando falle el cast (y cuando `unObjeto` sea null). Así que hay que tener cuidado con ello.

#### LINQ FirstOrDefault() y SingleOrDefault()

Las versiones sencillas `First()` y `Single()` lanzan una excepción cuando no hay nada. Las versiones `"OrDefault"` devuelven null en ese caso. Debes ser consciente de ello.

#### foreach

`foreach` lanza una excepción cuando intentas iterar una colección nula. Normalmente la causa de esto es un resultado nulo no esperado de un método que devuelve una colección.

```
 List<int> lista = null;    
 foreach(var v in lista) { } // excepción
```

Un ejemplo mas realista - seleccionar nodos de un documento XML. Se lanzará la excepción si los nodos no se encuentran pero una depuración inicial muestra que todas las propiedades son válidas:

```
 foreach (var nodo in myData.MyXml.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//Datos"))
```

---

## Maneras de evitarlo

#### Comprobar explícitamente `null` e ignorar los valores nulos.

Si prevés que la referencia alguna vez puede ser nula, puedes preguntar si es `null` antes de acceder a los miembros de la instancia:

```
void ImprimirNombre(Persona p) {
    if (p != null) {
        Console.WriteLine(p.Nombre);
    }
}
```

#### Comprobar explícitamente `null` y devolver un valor por defecto.

La llamada a los métodos que esperas que devuelvan una instancia podrían devolver `null`, por ejemplo cuando el objeto que se busca no se encuentra. Puedes optar por devolver un valor por defecto en estos casos:

```
string ObtenerCategoria(Libro b) {
    if (b == null)
        return "Desconocida";
    return b.Categoria;
}
```

#### Comprobar explícitamente `null` y lanzar una excepción personalizada.

También podrías lanzar una excepción personalizada, para poder capturarla en el código que llama al método:

```
string ObtenerCategoria(string titulo) {
    var libro = biblioteca.BuscarLibro(titulo);  // Esto podría devolver null
    if (libro == null)
        throw new LibroNoEncontradoException(titulo);  // Tu excepción personalizada
    return libro.Categoria;
}
```

#### Usa `Debug.Assert` si un valor nunca debería ser `null`, para capturar el problema antes de que la excepción sea lanzada.

Cuando en la etapa de desarrollo sepas que un método podría devolver `null` aunque esto no debería ocurrir nunca, puedes usar `Debug.Assert()` para parar el flujo de programa lo antes posible cuando pase:

```
string ObtenerTitulo(int libroExistenteID) {
    // Sabes que esto nunca debería devolver null.
    var libro = biblioteca.ObtenerLibro(libroExistenteID);  

    // La excepción se lanzará en la linea siguiente en lugar de la final del método.
    Debug.Assert(libro != null, "Biblioteca no devolvió ningun libro para el ID de un libro existente.");

    // ...otro código...

    return book.Titulo; // Nunca se lanzará una NullReferenceException en modo de depuración(Debug).
}
```

Este control no se realizará en tu compilación de lanzamiento (*Release Build*), causando que la `NullReferenceException` sea lanzada de nuevo cuando `libro == null` en tiempo de ejecución.

#### Usar `GetValueOrDefault()` en los tipos por valor "Anulables"(*nullables*) para obtener un valor por defecto cuando sean nulos.

```
DateTime? cita = null;
Console.WriteLine(cita.GetValueOrDefault(DateTime.Now));
// Mostrará el valor por defecto proporcionado (DateTime.Now), porque cita es null.

cita = new DateTime(2022, 10, 20);
Console.WriteLine(cita.GetValueOrDefault(DateTime.Now));
// Mostrará la fecha de la cita, no el valor por defecto
```

#### Usar el operador de comprobación de valores nulos (*null coalescing operator*): `??` [C#] o `If()` [VB].

La manera más corta de proporcionar un valor por defecto cuando se encuentra un valor nulo:

```
IService CrearServicio(ILogger log, Int32? nivel)
{
    var serviceImpl = new MiServicio(log ?? NullLog.Instance);

    // Fíjate que el "GetValueOrDefault()" de arriba puede ser reescrito para usar el operador ??
    serviceImpl.nivel = nivel ?? 5;
}
```

#### Usar el operador de condición nula: `?.` (disponible en C# 6 y VB.NET 14):

A este operador también se le llama de *navegación segura* o *Elvis* (por su forma). Si la expresión de la parte izquierda del operador es `null`, la parte derecha del mismo no será evaluada, y en su lugar se devolverá `null`. En este caso:

```
var titulo = persona.Titulo.ToUpper();
```

Si la persona no tiene un título, este código lanzará una excepción porque se está tratando de llamar a `ToUpper` en una propiedad con un valor nulo.

En C# 5 e inferiores, esto se puede solucionar así:

```
var titulo = persona.Titulo == null ? null : persona.Titulo.ToUpper();
```

Ahora la variable `titulo` será `null` en lugar de lanzar una excepción. C# 6 introduce una sintáxis mas corta que hace lo mismo:

```
var titulo = persona.Titulo?.ToUpper();
```

El resultado de esto es que a la variable `titulo` se le asignará null, y la llamada a `ToUpper` nunca se realizará si `persona.Titulo` es `null`.

Por supuesto, *todavía* tienes que comprobar que `title` no sea `null` o usar el operador de condición nula junto al operador de comprobación de valores nulos (`??`) para proporcionar un valor por defecto:

```
// comprobación normal de null
int longitudTitulo = 0;
if (titulo != null)
    longitudTitulo = titulo.Length; // Si titulo es null, esto lanzará una NullReferenceException

// combinando los operadores `?` y `??`
int longitudTitulo = titulo?.Length ?? 0;
```

*Esta respuesta es una traducción de la magnifica respuesta que se encuentra en la [versión en inglés de Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4660142/what-is-a-nullreferenceexception-and-how-do-i-fix-it)*

Comment: Buen trabajo excelente!!!

Answer (score 0):

En mi caso tenia un List inicializado en null

```
List<Object> lista = null;
```

Cambie la inicializacion por el tipo de objeto y se resolvió

```
List<Object> lista = new List<Object>();
```

Comment: Considera si lo dejarás como *wiki* añadir mas contexto y explicación a tu aporte