# object reference not set to an instance of an object

Tags: vb.net

> System.NullReferenceException: 'Object reference not set to an instance of an object.'

```
Dim conexion As SqlConnection 
conexion.ConnectionString = "integrated security=SSPI;data source=LAPTOP-2QDQLE6A\SQLEXPRESS;" & "persist security info=False;initial catalog=Estudiantes"
```

alguien me puede ayudar con este error?

Comment: Jeffry aunque ya obtuviste un respuesta bastante acertada , podrías leer [esta pregunta y respuesta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/75999/qu%C3%A9-es-una-nullreferenceexception-y-c%C3%B3mo-solucionarla) relacionada con tu problema.

Answer (score 2):

El problema es que en la primera línea estas declarando una variable de tipo `SqlConnection` pero al no instanciarla se queda con el valor `null`

Lo que debes hacer es en esa misma línea asignarle un valor, en este caso creando una nueva instancia de `SqlConnection` mediente el keyword `New`

```
Dim conexion As New SqlConnection 
conexion.ConnectionString = "integrated security=SSPI;data source=LAPTOP-2QDQLE6A\SQLEXPRESS;" & "persist security info=False;initial catalog=Estudiantes"
```