# ¿Cómo validar valores nulos VB.net?

Tags: vb.net

¿Cómo puedo validar si una variable esta `Null`?

ya intenté con:

```
If a Is null Then
 'a tiene valor nulo
Else
 'a es diferente de valor nulo
End If
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Para validar el valor `null` en VB.net se emplea `Nothing` que básicamente representa el valor predeterminado del tipo de dato que se esté empleando. la validación sería

```
If (a is Nothing) Then 
 ...
End If
```

También podría emplear el método [IsNullOrEmpty](https://msdn.microsoft.com/es-es/library/system.string.isnullorempty.aspx) de la clase String.

```
 If String.IsNullOrEmpty(a) Then
 . ..
 End If
```

> Como recomendación leer esta [pregunta y respuesta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/76861/nullreferenceexception-qu%C3%A9-es-y-c%C3%B3mo-puedo-solucionarla/76862#76862) que detalla más a fondo
>   sobre este punto