# Listar Imagenes en PictureBox procedentes de una List

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2015

Necesito ayuda para pasar las imágenes cargadas en una Lista a un `PictureBox`, tengo un función donde listo todas la imágenes (`StreetV` y `Ubicacion`) y necesito que dependiendo de la Id de la celda seleccionada de un `Datagridview` me cargue en el `Picture` la imagen correspondiente con esa `Id`.

Para listar las imágenes estoy utilizando esta función:

```
 Public Function GetImagenes() As List(Of ImagenesModelo)
    Dim ListImagenesDataModel = Repositorio.GetMostrarImagenes
    ListaImagenesViewModel = New List(Of ImagenesModelo)

    For Each item As Imagenes In ListImagenesDataModel

        ListaImagenesViewModel.Add(New ImagenesModelo With {
                .Id_Imagenes = item.Id_Imagenes,
                .StreetV = item.StreetV,
                .Ubicacion = item.Ubicacion
                 })
    Next
    Return ListaImagenesViewModel
End Function
Public Function FindById_Imagenes(filter As String) As IEnumerable(Of ImagenesModelo)
    Return ListaImagenesViewModel.FindAll(Function(emp) emp.Id_Imagenes = filter)
End Function
```

El list lo cargo de un tabla de la base de datos que tiene tres campos, uno es la `Id_Imagenes` y los otros dos son `StreetV` y `Ubicacion` que son imágenes y los tengo declarados como `Byte()`

Y con la función `FindById_Imagenes` estoy tratando de filtrar las imagenes `StreetV` con la `Id_Imagenes` correspondiente al valor de la Id de la celda seleccionada del `Datagridview`, trato de listar las imágenes `StreetV` por medio de:

```
PictureBox1.image = FindById_Imagenes(Datagridview.CurrentRow.Cell(0).value.ToString())
```

Comment: Bienvenido a [es.so]! Te recomiendo que hagas el [tour] y así ganar tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges/84/informed). Lee [ask] y [¿sobre qué temas puedo preguntar aquí?](http://es.stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) para aprender a realizar una buena pregunta.

Comment: Creo que debes intentar ser mas específico con tu duda. Donde te has quedado _pillado_? En que tienes problemas? Que es lo que no sabes hacer exactamente? Te recomiendo que leas los enlaces de mi anterior comentario para entender un poco mejor como funciona el sitio. Un saludo

Answer (score 0):

`FindById_Imagenes` devuelve un `IEnumerable`, pero `PictureBox1.Image` espera una sola imagen.

Lo que contiene `Ubicacion` es un `Byte()`, así que necesitas una función que convierta ese array a un `Image`, como por ejemplo la siguiente:

```
Public Shared Function ByteToImage(ByVal blob As Byte()) As Bitmap
    Dim mStream As MemoryStream = New MemoryStream()
    Dim pData As Byte() = blob
    mStream.Write(pData, 0, Convert.ToInt32(pData.Length))
    Dim bm As Bitmap = New Bitmap(mStream, False)
    mStream.Dispose()
    Return bm
End Function
```

Luego debes llamar a este método con el resultado de llamar a tu función de búsqueda, seleccionar el primer resultado, y obtener `Ubicacion`:

```
Dim imagen As Image =ByteToImage(FindById_Imagenes(Datagridview.CurrentRow.Cell(0).value.ToString()).First().Ubicacion)
PictureBox1.image = imagen
```

Ten en cuenta que si `FindById_Imagenes` no devuelve ninguna imagen, este código te lanzará una excepción que debes gestionar.

Comment: Ahora como ya me comentaste FindById_Imagenes me devuelve la excepción "Referencia a objeto no establecida como instancia de un objeto"

Comment: @Cede En ese ese caso, debes depurar tu código para ver que está pasando en ese método, y ver por qué  devuelve un NullReferenceException. [Esta respuesta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/76862/15301) puede servirte.

Comment: Muchisimas gracias Pikoh!!!!. Creo que el problema viene porque no se ha ejecutado la función GetImagenes para cargar la List.

Comment: Discúlpame un ultima preguntilla, una vez resuelta satisfactoriamente la pregunta que debo hacer¿?

Comment: @Cede lo habitual es que aceptes una respuesta si te ha ayudado (pulsando el check al lado de la misma) y votes positivamente tambien todas las respuestas que consideres utiles. Todo eso viene explicado en el [tour] :)