# ¿Como conectarse exitosamente a traves de un ConnectionString en appsettings.json a una DB?

Tags: c#, asp.net

Buen dia.
Soy nuevo programando en C#, estoy haciendo una pagina web donde las paginas hacen consultas a una DB y se me recomendo poner el ConnectionString en appSettings, revise en internet y me di cuenta que la manera "apropiada" era la siguiente:

1.-Agregar mi cadena de conexion en AppSettings (***myDb2***):

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

2.- Una vez realizado mandarlo llamar al intentar hacer la conexion, utilizando las siguientes referencias:

@using System.Configuration;
@using static System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager;

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Anteriormente yo hacia la Connection String directamente en el codigo y no habia problema alguno, ahora que intente cambiar al metodo el cual les comento cuando compilo el proyecto me aparece el siguiente error:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Quiero pedirles su ayuda para resolver este contratiempo ya que he intentado de distintas formas y me sigue apareciendo el mismo error, desconozco si ando omitiendo algun paso pero les agradeceria cualquier comentario o solucion.

Comment: lo estás haciendo en .Net Core?
ya intentaste con esta [respuesta](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31453495/how-to-read-appsettings-values-from-a-json-file-in-asp-net-core)?

Comment: Que tal! No la verdad no lo he intentado, si he visto soluciones parecidas a preguntas referentes a app settings pero pense que no aplicaba a lo mio ya que en la informacion que investigue solamente pedia los pasos anteriormente mencionados pero muchas gracias por la informacion, voy a verificar si me funciona:)

Comment: ¿Que tipo de proyecto es?

Comment: Es ASP.NET Core

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El problema que tienes es un poco complicado de explicar.

En primer lugar por lo que veo estás utilizando Razor Pages que es una de las opciones dentro de ASP.NET Core.  Razor pages está pensado cuando la página a mostrar requiere poca funcionalidad, mas es HTML que otra cosa y se requiere poco código del lado servidor (Lo cual no significa que no se puede hacer en realidad cualquier cosa, simplemente que está pensado en simplicidad en lugar de separar el código en varios componentes como ocurre al utlizar [MVC](https://learn.microsoft.com/es-mx/aspnet/core/tutorials/first-mvc-app/start-mvc?view=aspnetcore-6.0&tabs=visual-studio)).

En tu caso estás mezclando código de acceso a datos (probablemente usando ADO.NET) con HTML que está mas abajo (muy al estilo de PHP antiguo).

Volviendo al error.
El error que te sale es el famoso `NullReferenceException` (Aquí hay una excelente explicación de cuando ocurre y como solucionarlo: [NullReferenceException: ¿Qué es y cómo puedo solucionarla?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/76861/nullreferenceexception-qu%c3%a9-es-y-c%c3%b3mo-puedo-solucionarla)) Específicamente la vbariable que está en `null` es `ConnectionStrings["myDb2"]` lo cual significa que no pudo encontrar el key dentro de la configuración. Sin embargo a pesar que el archivo `appsettings.json` si contiene el connection string, el error está en pensar que el `ConfigurationManager` leerá ese archivo.

La razón es que estás usuando una clase heredada de .NET Framework que no es el método mas conveniente en ASP.NET Core.

Al usar

`@using static System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager`

Estás  intentando usar una clase legacy que existe en otro assembly: `System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager` y que probablemente esté intentando leer desde el `Web.Config` que es otro archivo de configuración utilizado en ASp.NET Clásico (.NET Framework).

La forma de ahcerlo en ASP.NET Core, y más específicamente en Razor Pages es la siguiente.

Si en el Explorador de soluciones expandes tu archivo llamado `G3Sequence.cshtml` notarás que existe anidado otro llamado ``G3Sequence.cshtml.cs`. Este contiene el código de G3SequeceModel.

En el constructor de este model deberás agregar un parámetro de tipo `IConfiguration` que el framework se encargará de pasar  y almacenarlo dentro del Model de tal forma que puedas accederlo desde el CSHTML.

Ejemplo:"

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.RazorPages;

namespace RazorPages.Pages
{
    public class IndexModel : PageModel
    {
        private readonly ILogger<IndexModel> _logger;
        public IConfiguration Configuration { get; }

        public IndexModel(ILogger<IndexModel> logger, IConfiguration configuration)
        {
            _logger = logger;
            Configuration = configuration;
        }

        public void OnGet()
        {

        }
    }
}
```

Luego para obtener la cadena de conexión desde la página en lugar de

```
System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["myDb2"].ConnectionString
```

Puedes simplemente llamar a:

```
Model.Configuration.GetConnectionString("myDb2")
```

Comment: Que tal Carlos, primero que nada agradecerte por la respuesta tan detallada, me ha servido perfectamente aparte de que tu explicacion ha sido clara y me ha dado una idea mas general ahora que estoy empezando, solo unas preguntas mas, actualmente estoy haciendo varias paginas parecidas donde hago conexiones a DB para ver informacion y hasta cierto punto planeo meter mas funcionalidades, ¿me recomendarias dejar de usar esto de Razor Pages? de ser asi ¿que otra opcion me recomendarias y por ultimo, ¿esa opcion serai muy dificil de aprender? 
Una vez mas gracias y saludos!

Comment: No es necesario dejar de usar Razor Pages, simplemente entender cómo funciona el patrón Front Controller. Primero puedes trasladar el código a métodos dentro del Model y luego incluso separarlo en capas adicionales y solo llamarlas desde el Model. En realidad lo que puedas hacer por debajo dependerá mucho de la arquitectura de tu solución. Razor Pages básicamente solo se encargará de la vista