# como pasar un dato de una tabla en sql a un label aun si la tabla esta vacia en visual basic

Tags: sql, vb.net

tengo este codigo para pasar el dato:

```
   Using Conn As New SqlConnection("Data Source=SAMUELSUSANA; Initial catalog=poovb;integrated security=true")
        Conn.Open()
        Dim ConsultaSQL = "SELECT TOP 1 Codigo_venta FROM tblventas ORDER BY Codigo_venta DESC"
        lblcodigo.Text = New SqlCommand(ConsultaSQL, Conn).ExecuteScalar().ToString()
    End Using
```

> Si mi tabla tiene al menos un codigo osea una venta funciona pero sino tiene arroja este error: Referencia a objeto no establecida como instancia de un objeto.

Comment: tu codigo se entiende.. pero para ver si esta todo ok, yo separaria toda la linea que pasa la info al textbox, de forma tal de ver cual de los objetos esta fallando.

Comment: no entiendo lo que me quieres decir

Comment: Podrías indicarnos al menos que el valor del `ExecuteScalar` esté obteniendo datos. Por ejemplo, `Dim Resultado = New SqlCommand(ConsultaSQL, Conn).ExecuteScalar()` y que `Resultado` no sea nulo (Nothing).

Comment: si esta obteniendo

Comment: podes debuguear y decirnos cual de todos los objetos es null??? porque el error es ese

Comment: mira https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/75999/qu%C3%A9-es-una-nullreferenceexception-y-c%C3%B3mo-solucionarla

Comment: ok, perdon ya vi el error el codigo sino encuentra datos osea sino hay codigos en la tabla si esta vacia manda ese error pero si hay si funciona.. como podria evitar que me tire ese error cuano no tenga ninguna venta aun

Comment: reescribe la pregunta con la informacion correcta, y ahi si podremos contestarla...

Comment: @SamuelIgnacioSusanaConfesor Recuerda que puedes [editar tu pregunta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/posts/92439/edit)

Comment: ya la edite @Davlio

Comment: necesitas validar si el objeto ExecuteScalar te esta devolviendo algo

Answer (score 0):

El problema se da debido a que la función `ExecuteScalar()` retorna un nulo y que al momento de realizar `ToString` te arroja dicho error.

---

A lo comentado, solo sería necesario que valides que el valor que obtienes no sea nulo antes de convertirlo a cadena y para luego asignarlo a tu `Label` lblcodigo.

```vb
lblcodigo.Text = ""

Using Conn As New SqlConnection("Data Source=SAMUELSUSANA; Initial catalog=poovb;integrated security=true")
    Conn.Open()
    Dim ConsultaSQL = "SELECT TOP 1 Codigo_venta FROM tblventas ORDER BY Codigo_venta DESC"

    Dim Resultado = New SqlCommand(ConsultaSQL, Conn).ExecuteScalar()
    If Not Resultado = Nothing Then
        lblcodigo.Text = Resultado.ToString
    End If

End Using
```

---

**Referencia:**

- [¿Qué es una NullReferenceException y cómo solucionarla?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/75999/qu%C3%A9-es-una-nullreferenceexception-y-c%C3%B3mo-solucionarla)

Comment: perdon por ser tan novato aun, pero se supone que con ese codigo si no tengo datos en la tabla que le va a pasar al label? por que no veo donde le asignes un valor si en dado caso el retorno del comando o execute scalar sea nulo

Comment: ok ya analize y vi lo que hace tu codigo, gracias.. una pregunta si quisiera hacer eso en c# me podrias explicar como hacerlo en esta pregunta o debo de publicar otra?

Comment: @SamuelIgnacioSusanaConfesor, al realizar `lblcodigo.Text = ""` le asigna una cadena vacía. Pero en caso sea nulo. ¿Que valor debería asignarle?

Comment: @SamuelIgnacioSusanaConfesor, como indicas que aún eres novato; por el momento podrías usar un convertidor de código, por ejemplo, [Convert Code de Telerik](http://converter.telerik.com/) y ver como sería para `C#`. Si tienes problemas puedes realizar una nueva pregunta.

Comment: esta bien ya lo arregle le asigne un valor 0 en caso de que sea nulo, voy a publicar la misma pregunta pero para c# por favor respondela

Comment: ah bueno gracias