# ¿Cómo puedo llenar un campo de una tabla referenciada en mi tabla principal con un datareader?

Tags: asp.net, ado.net

Cuando ejecuto mi View,me salta un error de null reference exception. Los demás campos llenan solo ese. He generado mi modelo con ADO Entity Framework

Mi SP devuelve la consulta de la img. Lo que quiero es llenar el campo y pese a que son compatibles no pasa nada.

```
public partial class ANAQUEL
    {
        public ANAQUEL()
        {
            this.DET_LOTE_ANAQUEL = new HashSet<DET_LOTE_ANAQUEL>();
        }

        public int NIDANAQUEL { get; set; }
        public int NIDALMACEN { get; set; }
        public string SCODANAQUEL { get; set; }
        public string SDESANAQUEL { get; set; }
        public int NESTADO { get; set; }
        public System.DateTime DFECREG { get; set; }
        public string SUSUREG { get; set; }

        public virtual ALMACEN ALMACEN { get; set; }
        public virtual ICollection<DET_LOTE_ANAQUEL> DET_LOTE_ANAQUEL { get; set; }
    }
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: por favor comparte la excepcion, y no una imagen de la misma la proxima vez.. ahi dice a.ALMACEN.sdesalmacen.. en los otros ese almacen no esta.. no puede ser ese el error???

Comment: Probablemente,como indica @gbianchi, `a.ALMACEN` es null. Añade `a.ALMACEN= new ALMACEN();` antes de la linea que te da la excepción a ver si te funciona

Comment: Y ya de paso, revisa [esta pregunta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/75999/15301)

Comment: Disculpen y muchas gracias,me ha funcionado exactamente lo que dijo Pikoh. Gracias también gbianchi

Comment: Posible duplicado de [¿Qué es una NullReferenceException y cómo solucionarla?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/75999/qu%c3%a9-es-una-nullreferenceexception-y-c%c3%b3mo-solucionarla)