# ¿Qué significa el error "TypeError: Cannot set/read properties of undefined/null" y cómo solucionarlo?

Tags: javascript

El siguiente código falla:

```js
let obj1,obj2;
obj2 = {
  atributo: 'texto'
};

console.log(obj1.atributo);
```

Mostrando en consola el mensaje:

> TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'atributo')

En Firefox (versión 111) el mensaje es:

> TypeError: obj1 is undefined

¿Qué significa y cómo puedo solucionarlo?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Basándonos del error

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'atributo' of undefined

Este error es muy comun estas intentando acceder a un elemento que no existe o su valor es undefined

```js
console.info("Ejemplo de acceso a un elemento del DOM que existe")
const div_existe = document.getElementById("existe")
console.log("div=", div_existe)
console.log("atributo div=" , div_existe.innerHTML) 
//caso que no existe 
console.info("Intentando Acceder a un elemento que NO Existe")
const div_no_existe = document.getElementById("no_existe")
console.log("div=", div_no_existe)
console.log("atributo div=", div_no_existe.innerHTML) //linea de error
```

```html
<div id="existe">chispas!!!</div>
```

[El error significa que no puedes acceder a esa propiedad](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Objetos_globales/TypeError), pero ¿por qué?

En el ejemplo que colocastes `obj1` esta declarado pero no utilizado, veamos el tipo de dato que nos arroja la prueba

```js
let obj1,obj2;
obj2 = {
  atributo: 'texto'
};
console.log("obj1->" , typeof(obj1));
console.log("obj2->" , typeof(obj2));
```

**¿Como solucionarlo?**

Para que de este error el valor de las variables deben ser **null** o **undefined**, lo que puedes hacer es lo siguiente:

- Verificar si el objeto esta declarado
- La asignación a tu Objeto no reciba parámetros null o undefined
- Si usas una librería externa verificar que este bien importada

```js
let libreriaExterna 
libreriaExterna.top = 3;
```

- Validar si el atributo existe (en el peor de los casos que tu objeto sea muy variable)

```js
let obj1 ,obj2
obj2 = {
  atributo: 'texto'
};

console.log("obj1: ¿está definido?" , typeof obj1 !== 'undefined');
console.log("obj2: ¿está definido?" , typeof obj2 !== 'undefined');
console.log("obj2.atributo: ¿está definido?" , typeof obj2.atributo !== 'undefined');
```

- Controlarlos con un Try/Cath(Javascript tiene eso? sí)

```js
let obj1,obj2;
obj2 = {
  atributo: 'texto'
};
try{
console.log(obj1.atributo);
}catch(e){
console.error(e.message," porque no existe el objeto");

}
```

Answer (score 12):

Siguiendo la serie de preguntas y respuestas de la misma temática

- [¿Qué es una NullReferenceException y cómo solucionarla?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/75999/qu%C3%A9-es-una-nullreferenceexception-y-c%C3%B3mo-solucionarla)
- [¿Cuál es la solución a todos los errores NullPointerException presentes, pasados y futuros?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/42977/cu%C3%A1l-es-la-soluci%C3%B3n-a-todos-los-errores-nullpointerexception-presentes-pasados)

Vamos a aclarar su equivalente en Javascript:

### ¿Qué significa?

El significado del mensaje de error *"Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'XXX' of undefined"* es:

> Error TypeError no capturado: No puedo leer la propiedad 'XXX' de `undefined`.

Y significa que estamos intentando acceder a una propiedad (atributo o función) de un identificador que no está definido.

En el ejemplo de la pregunta el error se produce porque tenemos dos variables, obj1 y obj2, donde a obj1 no se le ha asignado ningún valor, está *indefinida*. Si obj1 valiese `null`, el error sería similar.

### ¿Cómo solucionarlo?

La manera de solucionarlo es buscar en nuestro código el atributo `XXX` al que se intenta acceder (o definir) y entonces ver por qué el objeto padre es `null` o `undefined`.

Los motivos típicos suelen ser:

- Intentar acceder a una variable modificada por código asíncrono (la respuesta a una llamada AJAX o un evento como un click del ratón o la pulsación de una tecla) antes de que éste haya asignado un valor a dicha variable.
- Asumir que una función siempre devuelve un valor distinto de `null` o `undefined`: por ejemplo, si esta consulta nos devuelve una lista con 2 elementos, pero estamos intentando acceder a un inexistente tercer elemento:

  ```
  let myDivs = document.getElementsByClass('myDiv');
  let text=myDivs[2].innerText;
  // Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'innerText' of undefined
  ```