# Llamadas de Servicio angular5

Tags: angular

Tengo algunas dudas y algunos problemas.

Tengo varios componentes con la misma función:

```
Componente1:
  public headers: Object;
  public params: Object;
    sacarDatos(){
       const url='assets/dato1.json';
       this.service.sacarDatos(url).subscribe(
      data => {
        this.headers = data[0].headers;
        this.params = data[1].params;
      }
    }
    ngOnInit() {
        this.sacarDatos();
    }

Componente2:
  public headers: Object;
  public params: Object;

    sacarDatos(){
      const url='assets/dato2.json';
      this.service.sacarDatos(url).subscribe(
      data => {
        this.headers = data[0].headers;
        this.params = data[1].params;
      }
    }
    ngOnInit() {
        this.sacarDatos();
    }




   service:
          public sacarDatos(url:String):Observable<any>{
    return this.http.get<Object[]>(url);
  }
```

Y así hasta 14...

La duda es que si el componente 1 : mete en su header y en su params los datos de la función con la url datos1 y luego va el componente 2 y llama a la misma función, como el componente 1 está suscrito a esa función, cambiará los datos por los datos del componente 2 ?

No puedo comprobar esto porque con el código viejo Funciona:

Componente:

```
this.http.get('assets/dato1.json').subscribe(data => {
            this.headers = data[0].headers;
            this.params = data[1].params;
```

Pero cuando he cambiado el código al servicio, ha dejado de funcionar.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tus componentes **no** se suscriben **a una función**, se suscriben **a un `Observable`**, que es lo que devuelve esa función.

Cada llamada a esa función genera una instancia de  `Observable` nuevo, con lo que no tendrás dos componentes suscritos al mismo observable a menos que lo compartas de algún modo.

Comment: Podrías decirme porqué : Cannot read property 'SacarDatos' of undefined
    at ConfigurationComponent.SacarDatos(configuration.component.ts:59)
    at ConfigurationComponent.ngOnInit (configuration.component.ts:84)

Comment: La propiedad `SacarDatos`no existe... ¿has probado con `sacarDatos`? (empezando con minúscula)

Comment: Si perdón,es que cambio los nombres para no poner los reales de la aplicación, olvida la 'S' XD

Comment: En cualquier caso, te remito a la [respuesta genérica para ese error](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/169194/qu%C3%A9-significa-el-error-uncaught-typeerror-cannot-set-read-property-xxx-of-u)

Comment: Lo había declarado en el componente que no era, muchas gracias.