# Lista dinamica en Ionic

Tags: javascript, html, ionic, angular

les comento mi problema, consigo este error cuando quiero mostrar los datos de una lista creadas en el archivo .ts de mi pagina principal:

> Error: Uncaught (in promise): TypeError: Cannot read property 'nombre'
>   of undefined TypeError: Cannot read property 'nombre' of undefined
>       at Object.eval [as updateRenderer] (ng:///AppModule/EquiposPage.ngfactory.js:37:34)
>       at Object.debugUpdateRenderer [as updateRenderer] (http://localhost:8100/build/vendor.js:15109:21)

Aca van los scripts:

**Primera A (funciona perfecto)**

```
<ion-header>

  <ion-navbar>
    <ion-buttons>
      <button ion-button icon-only (click)="mostrarMenuLateral()">
          <ion-icon name="menu"></ion-icon>
        </button>
      </ion-buttons>
    <ion-title text-center>Primera - A</ion-title>

    <ion-segment [(ngModel)]="PrimeraA">
        <ion-segment-button value="Equipos">
          Equipos
        </ion-segment-button>
        <ion-segment-button value="Posiciones">
          Posiciones
        </ion-segment-button>
        <ion-segment-button value="Goleadores">
          Goleadores
        </ion-segment-button>
        <ion-segment-button value="Fixture">
          Fixture
        </ion-segment-button>
    </ion-segment>

  </ion-navbar>

</ion-header>


<ion-content >

    <div [ngSwitch]="PrimeraA">
        <ion-list *ngSwitchCase="'Equipos'">
                <ion-item *ngFor="let equipo of equiposPA"(click)="abrirEquipo()">
                  <img [src]="equipo.imagen" item-left>
                  <h3>{{equipo.nombre}}</h3>
                  <p small>{{equipo.localidad}}</p>
                </ion-item>        
        </ion-list>

        <ion-list *ngSwitchCase="'Posiciones'">
          <ion-item>
            <h2>Posiciones</h2>
          </ion-item>
          ...
        </ion-list>

        <ion-list *ngSwitchCase="'Goleadores'">
            <ion-item>
              <h2>Goleadores</h2>
            </ion-item>
            ...
        </ion-list>

        <ion-list *ngSwitchCase="'Fixture'">
            <ion-item>
              <h2>Fixture</h2>
            </ion-item>
            ...
        </ion-list>
      </div>

</ion-content>
```

**Primera-A .ts (funciona bien)**

```
export class PrimeraAPage {

  equiposPA:any [] = [
    {
      nombre:"Complejo Deportivo",
      localidad:"Justiniano Posse",
      imagen:"assets/imgs/complejo.png"
    },
    {
      nombre:"San Martin",
      localidad:"Monte Buey",
      imagen:"assets/imgs/sanmartin.png"
    },
    {
      nombre:"Defensores de Juventud",
      localidad:"Justiniano Posse",
      imagen:"assets/imgs/defensores.png"
    },
    {
      nombre:"Matienzo",
      localidad:"Monte Buey",
      imagen:"assets/imgs/matienzo.png"
    }
  ];

  constructor(public navCtrl: NavController, public navParams: NavParams, private menuCtrl: MenuController) {

  }

  ionViewDidLoad() {
    console.log('ionViewDidLoad PrimeraAPage');
  }

  mostrarMenuLateral()
  {
    this.menuCtrl.toggle();
  }
  abrirEquipo(equipo)
  {
    this.navCtrl.push(EquiposPage, { equipo: equipo });
  }
}
```

Y esta es la pagina donde quiero volver a utilizar esa lista pero me da el error

**equipo.html(da el error)**

```
<ion-header>

  <ion-navbar>
    <ion-title>Equipos</ion-title>
  </ion-navbar>

</ion-header>


<ion-content padding>
  <h1>{{item.nombre}}</h1>
</ion-content>
```

**equipo.ts**

```
export class EquiposPage {

  item;
  constructor(public navCtrl: NavController, public navParams: NavParams) {

    this.item = navParams.data.equipo;

  }

  ionViewDidLoad() {
    console.log('ionViewDidLoad EquiposPage');
  }

}
```

Desde ya les agradezco un moton y perdon si esta mal configurado el mensaje, es mi primero! 
Saludos!

Comment: Hola Juan , bienvenido a [es.so]. Por favor, lee el [tour] para aprender el funcionamiento básico del sitio. Lee tambien [ask] y [mcve] para más info en como mejorar la pregunta.  Un saludo.

Comment: Un consejo para la próxima vez: cuando pegues código, si lo seleccionas y pulsas `Ctrl + K`, automáticamente se formateará

Comment: Posible duplicado de [¿Qué significa el error "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set/read property 'XXX' of undefined/null" y cómo solucionarlo?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/169194/qu%c3%a9-significa-el-error-uncaught-typeerror-cannot-set-read-property-xxx-of-u) El problema es que item es `undefined`

Comment: Perdon por no leer el recorrido basico! Prometo hacerlo!
@Marc, no se porque no se visualiza correctamente el codigo, pero eso que coloque como comentario, asi es como tengo mi codigo.

Comment: @PabloLozano, comprendo el error, pero no veo donde tengo el problema, porque estoy declarando el item en el equipo.ts e igualandolo con navParams a la lista que necesito y que ya estoy usando en primeraA.ts. Gracias por responder!!