# Crear un array de objetos dinámicamente en javascript

Tags: javascript, array, objeto

Tenemos un objeto que es un curso perteneciente a un usuario:

```
var usercourse = new Object();
```

Ese objeto tiene propiedades o también llamados atributos, ¿no?:

- `usercourse.name = "Electrónica Digital";`
- `usercourse.progress = 75 //Significa que el usuario ha completado el 75% del curso;`

Hasta aquí, bien...
Un problema se da cuando quieres reflejar en el código el hecho de que un usuario tenga varios cursos, para lo cual estaba pesando en un array que me fuera recogiendo todos esos objetos.
Podríamos hacer lo siguiente:

```
var course1 = new Object();
course1.name = "Electrónica Digital";
course1.progress = 75;
var course2 = new Object();
course2.name = "Teoría de circuitos";
course2.progress = 18;
var course3 = new Object();
course3.name = "Diseño de cohetes";
course3.progress = 89;
var course4 = new Object();
course4.name = "Mecánica de fluidos";
course4.progress = 32;
var array = [course1, course2, course3, course4];
```

Ahora, **¿Cómo hacerlo dinámicamente?** Se me ocurre lo siguiente:
Queremos generar dinámicamente un array de objetos como el anteriormente descrito. El nombre del array de objetos es `usercourses`.
Había pensado lo siguiente:

```
for (i=0;i<numberofcourses;i++){
    usercourses[i] = new Object();
    usercourses[i].coursename = listofcourses[Math.floor(Math.random()*listofcourses.length)];
    usercourses[i].progress = Math.floor(Math.random()*100);
        }
```

- donde `listofcourses` es una lista de cursos y la expresión:
  `listofcourses[Math.floor(Math.random()*listofcourses.length)];`
   lo que hace es retornar un curso de forma aleatoria de la lista de
  cursos.
- donde `numberofcourses` es un número aleatorio que depende de la
  longitud de `listofcourses`, que es un listado con los nombres de los cursos disponibles.

**El problema**
La consola me arroja un error:

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'progress' of undefined

dándome el fallo en la siguiente línea de código:

```
usercourses[i].progress = Math.floor(Math.random()*100);
```

Comment: ¿Puedes poner cómo calculas usercourses? Poniendo un valor fijo en vez de numberofcourses tu código funciona sin problemas así que creo que el problema puede estar ahí.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pareciera ser un error de sintaxis, como que te faltó una `s` en `usercourses`?

```js
var usercourses = new Object(); // <--- aquí con "s"
var numberofcourses = 20;
var listofcourses = ['matemáticas', 'geografía', 'física', 'biología', 'filosofía'];
for (i = 0; i < numberofcourses; i++) {
  usercourses[i] = new Object();
  usercourses[i].coursename = listofcourses[Math.floor(Math.random() * listofcourses.length)];
  usercourses[i].progress = Math.floor(Math.random() * 100);
}

for (var c in usercourses) {
  console.log(c, usercourses[c]);
}
```

Comment: Muy bien! Me funciona pero prefiero sustituir `var usercourses = new Object();` por `var usercourses = [];`

Answer (score 2):

Creo que algo se te está escapando porque no es posible producir ese error en tu bucle:

```
// bucle que se repetirá "numberofcourses" veces
for (i=0;i<numberofcourses;i++) {
    // crea un objeto vacío
    usercourses[i] = new Object();
    // asigna un atributo al nuevo objeto
    usercourses[i].coursename = listofcourses[Math.floor(Math.random()*listofcourses.length)];
    // asigna un segundo atributo
    usercourses[i].progress = Math.floor(Math.random()*100);
}
```

Para que te de ese fallo, [el objeto debería ser undefined](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/169194/qu%C3%A9-significa-el-error-uncaught-typeerror-cannot-set-read-property-xxx-of-u) y en este caso no puede serlo.

En cualquier caso la notación que estás usando, aunque correcta, no es habitual entre los "veteranos" de Javascript, así que te pongo cómo lo haría yo:

- Casi nadie usa `new Object()`, poner simplemente `{}` es equivalente.
- Además puedes asignar los atributos directamente al declarar el objeto

  ```
  let userCourses=[]; //inicializo el array, es equivalente a new Array()

  for (let i = 0; i < numberofcourses; i++) {
    let name = listofcourses[Math.floor(Math.random() * listofcourses.length)];
    let p = Math.floor(Math.random() * 100);
    userCourses[i] = {
      coursename : name,
      progress : p
    };
  }
  ```

Answer (score 0):

Generar el array de objetos dinámicamente, suponiendo que tengas un array con los nombres de los cursos. Para esta primera parte, aquí tienes el codepen https://codepen.io/frontendnat/pen/ePgVRa?editors=1011

```
const courseTitles = ["Electrónica Digital", "Teoría de circuitos", "Diseño de cohetes"];
let courses = [];

for (let i = 0; i < courseTitles.length; i++) {
  let course = new Object();
// puedes jugar aquí un poco con el random
  let randomProgress = Math.floor(Math.random(100) + Math.random(250) + 1*10);
  course.name = courseTitles[i];
  course.progress = randomProgress;
  courses.push(course);
  console.log(courses);
}
```

Habia malinterpretado tu problema antes, pero igual dejo una posible aplicación, después ->
No estoy segura de por qué quieres dar un resultado aleatorio de porcentaje de participación, pero si quieres calcular la media, esta es una posible solución.

Aquí te dejo el codepen: https://codepen.io/frontendnat/pen/QZdMMv

```
<p class="info__cantidad">El alumno ha realizado <span id="cantidad"></span> cursos, con un porcentaje medio de participación del <span id="participacion"></span> %</p>
```

Y el JS

```
const course1 = {
  "name": "Electronica Digital",
  "progress": 75
};
const course2 = {
  "name": "Teoria de Circuitos",
  "progress": 18
};
const course3 = {
  "name": "Diseño de Cohetes",
  "progress": 89
};

const listofcourses = [];
listofcourses.push(course1, course3, course2);
console.log(listofcourses.length);

let cantidad = listofcourses.length;
document.getElementById('cantidad').innerHTML = cantidad;

let participacion = [];
for (i = 0; i < listofcourses.length; i++){
  console.log(listofcourses[i].name);
  console.log(listofcourses[i].progress);
  participacion.push(listofcourses[i].progress);
};

let mediaProgreso = Math.floor((participacion.reduce((a, b) => a + b, 0)) / listofcourses.length);
document.getElementById('participacion').innerHTML = mediaProgreso;
```

Comment: Hola Nat, no veo que la respuesta tenga relación con la pregunta del OP. Él quiere resolver un problema al generar dinámicamente el array de objetos y tu respuesta no hace mención a ello...

Comment: Tienes razón, lo he editado.