# Por qué genera el error cannot read property 'click' of undefined cuando hay un solo registro

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Estoy trabajando con `AngularJS` y tengo en mi `HTML` una lista desplegable *Tipificacion* que cuando seleccionan la opción *oK* me activa automáticamente un `CheckBox` así:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

El problema que tengo es que funciona perfecto cuando hay mas de un registro, cuando hay uno solo me genera este error:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Este es mi `HTML` de la lista desplegable:

```
<select ng-model="data.tipificacion" class="btn btn-default btn-xs grupo-select" name="tipificacion" style="width:100px" ng-change="palancatv(data,$index)">
<option value="Ok">Ok</option>
<option value="Rechazado por posible fraude">Rechazado por posible fraude</option>
<option value="Rechazado por mal ingreso">Rechazado por mal ingreso</option>
<option value="Duplicado">Duplicado</option>
<option value="Error de despacho(faltó gestión)">Error de despacho(faltó gestión)</option>
<option value="Reenvio Falla">Reenvio Falla</option>
<option value="error del sistema">Error del Sistema</option>
```

Este es mi `HTML` del `CheckBox`:

```
<span class="small">
<input type="checkbox" class="flipswitch" style="width:50px" ng-model="data.acepta" name="acepta" id="acepta" >
```

Y este es mi `JS`:

```
$scope.palancacp = function(data,idxcp)
{
    var TIPICP = $scope.contingenciasPortafolio.map((doc)=>doc.tipificacionPortafolio);
    var PALANCACP= $scope.contingenciasPortafolio.map((doc)=>doc.aceptaPortafolio);

    if(TIPICP[idxcp]=="Ok") 
    { 
        aceptacp[idxcp].click();
    } 
    else if(PALANCACP[idxcp]==true)
    {
        aceptacp[idxcp].click();
    }
    else
    {
        aceptacp[idxcp].checked=false;
    }                   
}
```

saludos cordiales

Comment: Posible duplicado de [¿Qué significa el error "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set/read property 'XXX' of undefined/null" y cómo solucionarlo?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/169194/qu%c3%a9-significa-el-error-uncaught-typeerror-cannot-set-read-property-xxx-of-u)

Comment: No sé qué es `aceptacp`, pero te está diciendo que en `aceptacp[idxcp]` no hay ningún valor guardado

Answer (score 0):

lo que necesitas conseguir puede realizarse de forma más simple utilizando ng-options y ng-true-value.

Esto es porque los selects trabajan mejor con ng-options en angularJs, manejan mejor el two-way databinding, y con ng-true-value en un checkbox puedes controlar qué valor actua como valor verdadero para activarse.

El siguiente código de ejemplo muestra cómo realizarlo:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" ng-app="app">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>

    <div ng-controller="DemoCtrl">
        <select name="tipificacion" ng-model="data.tipificacion" ng-options="tipificacion as tipificacion in tipificaciones track by $index"></select>
        <input type="checkbox" ng-model="data.acepta" ng-true-value="'OK'">
    </div>

    <script>
    angular
        .module('app', [])
        .controller('DemoCtrl', $scope => {
            $scope.tipificaciones = ['OK', 'Rechazado por posible fraude'];

        });
    </script>

</body>
</html>
```

Más información en: [checkbox](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/input/input%5Bcheckbox%5D), [ng-options](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngOptions)