# No soy capaz de pasar un objeto al abrir un dialogo en Angular 6

Tags: angular6

he estado intentado que al abrir un dialogo se le pase un objeto para poder editarlo llamando a la Api con un put pero al abrir el dialogo me aparece como undefined aun poniendo un console.log donde se muestra que se lo estoy pasando bien.[image]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Ayuda por favor y gracias de antemano.

Comment: Posible duplicado de [¿Cuál es la solución a todos los errores NullPointerException presentes, pasados y futuros?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/42977/cu%c3%a1l-es-la-soluci%c3%b3n-a-todos-los-errores-nullpointerexception-presentes-pasados)

Comment: Posible duplicado de [¿Qué significa el error "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set/read property 'XXX' of undefined/null" y cómo solucionarlo?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/169194/qu%c3%a9-significa-el-error-uncaught-typeerror-cannot-set-read-property-xxx-of-u)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Posiblemente estés poniéndole un nombre diferente en el ts del diálogo. Llamalo con el mismo nombre cuando crees la variable. restaurante: RestauranteDto;