# Error - Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property '0' of undefined

Tags: javascript

Buen día soy nuevo en esto de programación, me marca este error:

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property '0' of undefined

donde `valores.push (elm.valores[0].valor)` ojalá me puedan ayudar que es lo que tengo mal y cual sería la manera correcta de hacer la validación gracias.

```
function enviaVectoresAPIestratos() {
    var valores = [];
    for (var elm of SuperArreglo) {
        valores.push(elm.Valores[0].Valor)
    }
    obtenDataEstrtosApi(valores);
}
```

Comment: Posible duplicado de [¿Qué significa el error "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set/read property 'XXX' of undefined/null" y cómo solucionarlo?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/169194/qu%c3%a9-significa-el-error-uncaught-typeerror-cannot-set-read-property-xxx-of-u)

Comment: ¿Qué es `SuperArreglo` y qué datos tiene?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suponiendo que **SuperArreglo** es un JSON obtenido por AJAX podrías modificar tu código de la siguiente manera:

```
    function enviaVectoresAPIestratos() {
    var valores = [];
    for (var elm in SuperArreglo) {
        valores.push(Valores[elm])
    }
    obtenDataEstrtosApi(valores);
}
```

Me cuentras como te va!

Comment: gracias encontré la solución añadiendo un if dentro del for if (typeof elm.Valores != "undefined")

Comment: Por nada amigo, se me olvido mencionar el factor del "valor nulo". Saludos!

Answer (score 0):

Corrígeme si me equivoco, pero lo que tu quieres es introducir cada valor de SuperArreglo, en tu array definido como valores.
Sería así:

```
function enviaVectoresAPIestratos() {
 var valores = [];
 for(var elm of SuperArreglo) {
     valores.push(elm)
 }
}
```

Como información adicional, te diré que la función push() añade los elementos al final del array.