# ¿Qué diferencia hay entre inicializar un objeto a nulo o inicializarlo vacío?

Tags: javascript, nodejs

Tengo entendido que cuando quieres crear un nuevo objeto en Javascript, lo mejor es usar notación JSON:

```js
let foo1 = {};
let foo2 = {};

foo1 = `Hola ${user}`;
foo2.name = user;
```

Por lo que me he llevado una sorpresa cuando, al revisar código que me ha sido legado, me he encontrado con algo como:

```js
let httpResponse = null;

if (condition) {
    httpResponse = 'Error processing request'
} else {
    httpResponse = JSON.parse(data)
}
```

**¿Por qué mis compañeros han puesto null para inicializar el objeto?** ¿Hay diferencias entre ambas maneras?

Comment: Supongo que para que luego en el código puedan poner `if(httpResponse)` que en el caso de estar inicializado a null la condición será `false` en cambio inicializado como un objeto vacío la condición sería `true`

Comment: Realmente ninguna de las inicializaciones (salvo *foo2*) parece necesaria, ya que el valor asignado no se usa... ¿Una manía de cuando tus compañeros programaban en C, quizás?

Comment: @SJuan76 no he querido meter todo, porque esto es una respuesta http que cambia según un `if` de varias ramas y más de 1000 líneas. Puede que me haya comido algo.

Comment: @David no he visto ninguna comprobación: se cambia el contenido de la respuesta desde string hasta un objeto complejo según diferentes condiciones y luego se devuelve, pero nada de `if(httpResponse)`.

Comment: Pues básicamente es la unica diferencia entre un objeto inicializado a null e inicializado a algún valor aunque sea un objeto vacío. Será alguna manía de dejar las cosas inicializadas.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Voy por partes:

```
let foo1 = {};
let foo2 = {};

foo1 = `Hola ${user}`;
foo2.name = user;
```

Este código es *incorrecto*. Funciona, pero hace cosas que no son necesarias:

```js
const user='Tú';
let foo1 = {};
let foo2 = {};

console.log(typeof foo1);
foo1 = `Hola ${user}`;
console.log(typeof foo1);

foo2.name = user;
console.log(foo2);
```

Como puedes ver, primero asignas un objecto vacío a `foo1`, pero luego le asignas un `string`, así que el objeto inicial se ha perdido. En el caso de foo2 tiene sentido porque estás añadiendo propiedades al objeto ya creado.

Lo mismo pasa con este otro código:

```
let httpResponse = null; // es null

if (condition) {
    httpResponse = 'Error processing request' //es un string
} else {
    httpResponse = JSON.parse(data) // es un objeto
}
```

Ponerlo a null es innecesario porque tienes un `if-else`. Si tuvieses un `if-else-if`, existiría la posibilidad de que no se asignara nada

Por último, asumamos que tu código realmente es más complejo del que has puesto en el ejemplo y necesita un valor por defecto. Inicializar a `null` puede tener sentido si tus comprobaciones son estrictas, pero hay que recordar que `null == undefined` es siempre `true`. De hecho, mientras no trabajes con números lo más cómodo es hacer algo como

```
if (variable) {
   ...
}
```

donde `variable` se considera *falso* si es null, undefined o un string vacío. Un objeto (vacío o no), incluyendo un array (vacío o no) o un string con longitud mayor a 0 se considera *verdadero*. Con los números, 0 es falso y cualquier otro valor, positivo o no, es verdadero.

Entonces, ¿cuál es la diferencia entre tener un objeto vacío y tener null/undefined? Pues lo que hemos visto con foo2, a un objeto vacío puedes ir añadiéndole las propiedades que necesites mientras que a un null/indefined no, ya que provocaría el [ya conocido error *Cannot set property ...* of null](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/169194/qu%C3%A9-significa-el-error-uncaught-typeerror-cannot-set-read-property-xxx-of-u):

```js
let vacio={};
let nulo = null;

vacio.a='hola';

try {
  nulo.a='hola';
} catch (e) {
  console.log('Algo falla:',e.toString());
}
```

Comment: Quiero aclarar que en mi caso real es un `if-else if-else` en el que unas veces se iguala a un string (un mensaje de error), y otras se genera un objeto complejo (una respuesta).