# ¿Cómo obtener el valor del Id de un elemento HTML a través de una variable en JavaScript?

Tags: javascript

Estaba desarrollando una función que me permitiese aligerar la redundancia de mi código en JavaScript, por eso mismo quería enviar enviar la Id como parámetro de la siguiente forma:

```
function miFuncion(id_variable) {

var variable = document.getElementById(id_variable).value;

/*Mas tareas
  durante el resto
  de la funcion*/
}
```

Sin embargo, no me funciona, he considerado que pudiera tratarse de la falta de comillas y he intentado de las siguientes formas, sin resultados.

```
var variable = document.getElementById('id_variable').value;

var variable = document.getElementById('' + id_variable + '').value;

var variable = document.getElementById('"' + id_variable + '"').value;
```

Espero alguien pueda ayudarme con esto y lanzarme algo de claridad al respecto. Gracias por su tiempo.

Comment: Revisaste si el valor de id_variable es correcto?

Comment: Cual es el valor de id_variable ? si tienes elementos en el DOM con el id que devuelve id_variable ?

Comment: Así es, intente por ejemplo el pasarle un Id fijo de un checkbox, cuando se lo paso por ejemplo como document.getElementById('check_1').value; y funciona correctamente. A continuación decidí probar creando una variable test con ese mismo valor: var test = check_1; document.getElementById(test).value; Esto tampoco me dio resultados.

Comment: Las preguntas que buscan ayuda con la depuración de código deben de incluir un [mcve] (te falta el HTML)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hice un ejemplo muy sencillo, primero tomo el valor del primer input, suponiendo que necesitas ese valor para seleccionar otro elemento HTML, entonces tengo que llamar a la función dónde le paso como parámetro mi resultado del primer input y en la función con nombre `segunda` puedo poner el nombre del parámetro que e crea conveniente siempre tendrá el valor que le hagas pasado inicialmente, después solo tienes que obtener el valor de la etiqueta HTML con el nombre de la variable que hayas pasado por parámetro, no necesitas agregar comillas ya que el valor viene como string, espero haber sido claro, cualquier duda pregunta

```js
window.addEventListener('load',function (){

  let text = document.getElementById('texto').value;

  segunda(text);

function segunda(var1){

  let text2 = document.getElementById(var1).value;
  
  console.log(text2);
  
}

});
```

```html
<input type="text" id="texto" value="Hola">
<input type="text" id="Hola" value="Loquesea">
```

Answer (score 3):

Seguramente lo que te esté pasando es que estás tratando de capturar el `value` del elemento que quieres guardar en `var variable` antes de que este se encuentre cargado en el **DOM** ocasionando que no puedas encontrar ese elemento.

Cuando esto sucede el navegador suele arrojarnos un error por consola del tipo:

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'value' of null

El error nos está indicando que se está tratando de leer la propiedad `value` del valor `NULL`, que es justo lo que obtenemos cuando tratamos de obtener un elemento que no ha cargado todavía.

Existen varias alternativas para evitar eso. Una de ellas es colocar la etiqueta `<script>` abajo del todo de tu **HTML**, justo antes de cerrar la etiqueta `<body>` de esta manera te aseguras de que tus funciones de **Javascript** siempre hagan referencia a elementos ya cargados en el **DOM**.

```html
<input id="nombre" value="Pepe">

<script>
  var id = "nombre";
  
  miFuncion(id);
  
  function miFuncion(id_variable) {
    let variable = document.getElementById(id_variable).value;
    alert(variable);
  }
</script>
```

Hagamos una prueba, voy a usar el mismo código que usé arriba cambiando sencillamente la posición de la etiqueta `<script>` para ponerla por encima del `<input>` cuyo valor deseamos capturar.

```html
<script>
  var id = "nombre";

  miFuncion(id);

  function miFuncion(id_variable) {
    let variable = document.getElementById(id_variable).value;
    alert(variable);
  }
</script>

<input id="nombre" value="Pepe">
```

Si lo ejecutamos, se puede apreciar que el código deja de funcionar y en lugar del resultado deseado obtenemos un precioso mensaje de error en nuestra consola del navegador.

Otra alternativa que tenemos es usar una de las funciones disponibles que nos permiten controlar cuando el **DOM** ha terminado de cargar y así podemos ejecutar nuestro código solamente cuando esto haya sucedido.

```html
<script>
  window.addEventListener('load',function (){
    var id = "nombre";
    miFuncion(id);
  });
  
  function miFuncion(id_variable) {
    let variable = document.getElementById(id_variable).value;
    alert(variable);
  }
</script>

<input id="nombre" value="Pepe">
```

Aquí se puede apreciar como encontrándose el `<input>` por debajo del `<script>` se consigue hacer correctamente referencia al elemento. Esto sucede gracias a que estamos atachando a nuestro **DOM** un evento `load` que a través de una función anónima nos permite que el código que se encuentre dentro de dicha función se ejecute solamente cuando ha cargado el **DOM**.

Comment: aqui tienes una buena pregunta sobre [¿Qué significa el error “Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set/read property 'XXX' of undefined/null” y cómo solucionarlo?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/169194/qu%c3%a9-significa-el-error-uncaught-typeerror-cannot-set-read-property-xxx-of-u)

Answer (score 2):

Te coloco un código que hace lo que tu planteas, revisa si hay alguna cosa que haces diferente o no estés considerando

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <body>
    <input type="checkbox" id="check1">
    <button onclick="miFuncion('check1')">llamar funcion</button><br>
    <input type="checkbox" id="check2">
    <button onclick="miFuncion('check2')">llamar funcion</button><br>
    <input type="checkbox" id="check3">
    <button onclick="miFuncion('check3')">llamar funcion</button>

    <script>
    function miFuncion(id_variable) {

    var variable = document.getElementById(id_variable).checked;

    alert(variable);
    }
    </script>
    </body>
    </html>
```