# cannot read property 'split' of null

Tags: php, javascript

Tengo este error y me esta volviendo no lo logro solucionar es en JavaScript, lo que pasa es que es un sistema que calendariza mediante un cron cuando se va a ejecutar el aplicativo pero tengo este error y no se cómo corregirlo:

```
function doWork(){
    makeCall('data/getSchedule.php','',function(err,res){
        var lastMovedDay= res.lastDay;
        var lastExecDay= res.lastExec;

        if($("input[name=tipo]:checked").val()=="especifico"){
            var _firstExec= $('#1Ejecucion').val();
            var _dayExec= $('#diaEjecucion').val();
            var arrayDate= _firstExec.split('-');
            var _hour= $("#horaEspecifica").val();
            var _begin= $("#diaDesde").val();
            var _end= $("#diaHasta").val();
            var date= new Date(arrayDate[0], (arrayDate[1]-1), arrayDate[2]);
            var arrayLastExec=lastMovedDay.split('-');
            var lastDate= new Date(arrayLastExec[0], arrayLastExec[1]-1, arrayLastExec[2]);

            lastDate.setDate(lastDate.getDate() + 7);

            if(_dayExec==days[date.getDay()]){
                if(lastDate<=date){                 
                    params = {
                        dayExec:_dayExec,
                        hour:_hour,
                        firstExec:_firstExec,
                        begin:_begin,
                        end:_end
                    }
                    makeCall('data/guardarCalendarizacion.php',params,function(err,res){
                        alert("Calendarización Actualizada");
                    });
                }
                else{
                    alert("La fecha de primera ejecución debe ser mayor al  "+ lastDate.toISOString().slice(0, 10));
                }
            }
            else{
                alert("El día de primera ejecución debe ser un "+ $('#diaEjecucion').val());
            }
        }
        else{
            var _hour= $("#horaRecurrente").val();
            var _rec=parseInt($("#diasRec").val());
            var today= new Date();
            today.setHours(0,0,0,0);
            var arrayLastDay=lastMovedDay.split('-');           
            var lastDate= new Date(arrayLastDay[0], arrayLastDay[1]-1, arrayLastDay[2]);
            lastDate.setDate(lastDate.getDate()+1);
            var limitMin= new Date(today);          
            limitMin.setDate(limitMin.getDate() - _rec);            
            var limit= new Date(today);
            limit.setDate(limit.getDate() -1);
            var next= new Date(today);
            next.setDate(next.getDate() + _rec-1);
            console.log(_rec+ " "+limitMin + " "+ lastDate);
            var save= true;

            if(limitMin>lastDate){
                console.log("mayor");
                limitMin.setDate(limitMin.getDate()-1);
                var r = confirm("Los tiempos del rango "+ lastDate.toISOString().slice(0, 10)+" - "+limitMin.toISOString().slice(0, 10)+ " no se va trasladar. \n ¿Desea Guardar la calendarización?");
                if (!r) {
                    save=false;
                }           
            }
            if(save){
                params = {
                    hour:_hour,
                    rec:_rec
                }
                makeCall('data/guardarCalendarizacion.php',params,function(err,res){
                    alert("Calendarización Actualizada");
                });
            }
        }


    });
}
```

Debo mencionar que los valores nulos me los trae desde el archivo "getschedule.php", en esta parte para ser más exactos:

```
require_once('data.php');
header('Content-Type: application/json; charset=UTF-8;');
//config
$dbhost = $hostname;
$dbname = $database;

//connection
$m = new MongoClient("mongodb://$dbhost");
$db = $m -> $dbname;

//selecting collection
$calendario = $db->ejecucion;

$result = $calendario->findOne();
if($result['recurrence']){
    $return = array(
        'recurrence'=>true,
        'rec'=>$result['period'],
        'hour'=>$result['hour'],
        'min'=>$result['min'],
        'lastExec'=>$result['last_execution'],
        'lastDay' =>$result['last_day']
    );
}
else{
    $return = array(
        'recurrence'=>false,
        'dayExec'=>$result['day_week'],
        'hour'=>$result['hour'],
        'min'=>$result['min'],
        'lastExec'=>$result['last_execution'],
        'firstExec'=>$result['first_execution'],
        'begin'=>$result['range']['start'],
        'end'=>$result['range']['end'],
        'lastDay' =>$result['last_day']
    );
}

echo json_encode($return, JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE);
```

Pero ¿dónde debería colocar el `if` para comprobar o cómo debería setear la variable `lastMoveyDay` para que no me traiga los valores nulos?

Comment: cual es tu problema

Comment: Bienvenido. Las preguntas que buscan ayuda con la depuración de código deben de incluir un [mcve]. En tu caso en particular falta que indiques si estás usando jQuery y en tal caso la versión, además de indicar si el mensaje de error textual y dónde se muestra dicho error.

Comment: Hola @Ruben muchas gracias por responder estoy usando jQuery 2.1.3 y me dice que el error es en la linea **var arrayLastExec=lastMovedDay.split('-');**

Comment: El error está bastante claro, no puedes hacer `.split()` de un valor `null`. Es decir que `lastMovedDay` es `null`. Deberías depurar el código para comprobarlo y ver en que casos te llega como `null`, y si solo se debería de ejecutar esa parte del código si no es `null` comprobarlo en un `if`

Comment: hola @Rubén muchas gracias por responder de nuevo mi comentario pero dime donde podria colocar el if para comprobar? dentro o fuera del if? que ya esta hay, al igual puse de donde trae esos valores ya que los esta tomando de una coleccion de una base de datos de mongo pero esa coleccion no existe porque no me la crea, entonces como se podria setear ese valor?

Comment: Quien te "respondió de nuevo" fue @x3k_js :)

Comment: Posible duplicado de [¿Qué significa el error "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set/read property 'XXX' of undefined/null" y cómo solucionarlo?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/169194/qu%c3%a9-significa-el-error-uncaught-typeerror-cannot-set-read-property-xxx-of-u)

Answer (score 0):

El problema es que `res.lastDay` lo estas recibiendo con valor `null` y no puedes hacer `split()`. En este caso podrías usar el [operador ternario](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Operadores/Conditional_Operator) para controlarlo, algo como esto:

```
var arrayLastExec = lastMoveDay == null ? null : lastMovedDay.split('-');
```

Cuando `lastMoveDay` viene nulo, le asignas el valor `null` a `arrayLastExec`. En caso contrario, haces el `split()`.

**EDICIÓN:**

Parece que `arrayDate` también es `null`. En este caso podrías controlarlo igual:

```
var lastDate= arrayLastExec == null ? null : new Date(arrayLastExec[0], arrayLastExec[1]-1, arrayLastExec[2]);
```

**EDICIÓN 2:**

Viendo que varios campos dependen de *lastMoveDay* mejor controlarlo todo con un único bloque `if`. Si `lastMoveDay` es nulo, no podrá calcular `arrayLastExec` ni `lastDate`.

```
makeCall('data/getSchedule.php','',function(err,res){
        var lastMovedDay= res.lastDay;
        var lastExecDay= res.lastExec;
        if($("input[name=tipo]:checked").val()=="especifico"){
            var _firstExec= $('#1Ejecucion').val();
            var _dayExec= $('#diaEjecucion').val();
            var arrayDate= _firstExec.split('-');
            var _hour= $("#horaEspecifica").val();
            var _begin= $("#diaDesde").val();
            var _end= $("#diaHasta").val();
            var date= new Date(arrayDate[0], (arrayDate[1]-1), arrayDate[2]);
            var arrayLastExec;
            var lastDate;
            if (lastMoveDay != null) {
                arrayLastExec = lastMovedDay.split('-');
                lastDate= new Date(arrayLastExec[0], arrayLastExec[1]-1, arrayLastExec[2]);

                lastDate.setDate(lastDate.getDate() + 7);
                if(_dayExec==days[date.getDay()]){
                    if(lastDate<=date){                 
                        params = {
                            dayExec:_dayExec,
                            hour:_hour,
                            firstExec:_firstExec,
                            begin:_begin,
                            end:_end
                        }
            }
```

**EDICIÓN 3 (Se ha actualizado la pregunta):**

Se puede hacer de muchas maneras distintas. Yo personalmente me decantaría por comprobar al inicio del método `makeCall` si el valor `res.lastDay` tiene valor. En el caso de que no lo tenga, no me molestaría en seguir y mostraría un mensaje de error:

```
function doWork(){
    makeCall('data/getSchedule.php','',function(err,res){

        if (res.lastDay == null) {
            alert('Error. lastDay no tiene valor...'); 
            return;
        }

        var lastMovedDay= res.lastDay;
        var lastExecDay= res.lastExec;

        ....
```

Comment: hola, muchas gracias por ayudarme, lo intente con la linea de codigo que me sugeriste pero ahora me dice que cannot read property '0' of null y para ser mas exactos el problema estaria aqui en esta linea **var lastDate= new Date(arrayLastDay[0], arrayLastDay[1]-1, arrayLastDay[2]);**

Comment: @danielrubio he heditado la respuesta.

Comment: ya probe y tambien se puede controlar pero ahora me dice que setDate es nulo tambien **lastDate.setDate(lastDate.getDate()+1);** y me imagino que los que siguen abajo tambien van a dar el mismo error y pues creeria yo que con el getDate, como se podria hacer en ese caso ?

Comment: `setDate()` no puede ser nulo, ya que es una función. El problema es `lastDate`, que obviamente, con la solución que acabas de implementar, es nulo. Todo esto viene siendo un tanto lo mismo, debes controlar los valores nulos para que funcione correctamente.

Comment: y como seria para controlar esa linea  me podrias ayudar por favor para tomar de ejemplo **lastDate.setDate(lastDate.getDate()+1);**

Comment: me podrias ayudar por favor con la linea de codigo @zeross

Comment: He editado la respuesta @danielrubio

Comment: He vuelto a editar la respuesta @danielrubio

Comment: muchas gracias ha sido de gran ayuda pero como hago para que no me de el valor null, yo quiero que cuando rellene los campos estos se guarden en la base de datos y no me los pase null como hago ?, digamos que validacion es para que me digan si estan vacios pero entonces como hago para que ya no esten vacios si no que tengan un valor?

Comment: @danielrubio, en ese caso el problema podría estar en `getSchedule.php`, concretamente cuando haces la asignación `'lastDay' =>$result['last_day']`. Tendrías que averiguar por qué `$result['last_day']` no tiene valor.