# poner un ternario a una funcion en javascript

Tags: php, javascript, mongodb

Tengo un pequeño problema y es que estoy colocando un ternario para unas variables para que al rellenar unos valores no me de como null pero ahora me da un error y me dice que `setDate` tambien da `null`:

```
function doWork(){
    makeCall('data/getSchedule.php','',function(err,res){
        var lastMovedDay= res.lastDay;
        var lastExecDay= res.lastExec;

        if($("input[name=tipo]:checked").val()=="especifico"){
            var _firstExec= $('#1Ejecucion').val();
            var _dayExec= $('#diaEjecucion').val();
            var arrayDate= _firstExec == null ? null: _firstExec.split('-');
            var _hour= $("#horaEspecifica").val();
            var _begin= $("#diaDesde").val();
            var _end= $("#diaHasta").val();
            var date= new Date(arrayDate[0], (arrayDate[1]-1), arrayDate[2]);
            var arrayLastExec = lastMovedDay == null ? null : lastMovedDay.split('-');
            var lastDate= arrayLastExec == null ? null : new Date(arrayLastExec[0], arrayLastExec[1]-1, arrayLastExec[2]);
            lastDate.setDate (lastDate.getDate() + 7);
            if(_dayExec==days[date.getDay()]){
                if(lastDate<=date){                    
                    params = {
                        dayExec:_dayExec,
                        hour:_hour,
                        firstExec:_firstExec,
                        begin:_begin,
                        end:_end
                    }
                    makeCall('data/guardarCalendarizacion.php',params,function(err,res){
                        alert("Calendarización Actualizada");
                    });
                }
                else{
                    alert("La fecha de primera ejecución debe ser mayor al  "+ lastDate.toISOString().slice(0, 10));
                }
            }
            else{
                alert("El día de primera ejecución debe ser un "+ $('#diaEjecucion').val());
            }
        }
        else{
            var _hour= $("#horaRecurrente").val();
            var _rec=parseInt($("#diasRec").val());
            var today= new Date();
            today.setHours(0,0,0,0);
            var arrayLastDay= lastMovedDay == null ? null: lastMovedDay.split('-');            
            var lastDate= arrayLastDay == null ? null : new Date(arrayLastDay[0], arrayLastDay[1]-1, arrayLastDay[2]);
            lastDate.setDate(lastDate.getDate()+1);
            var limitMin= new Date(today);            
            limitMin.setDate(limitMin.getDate() - _rec);            
            var limit= new Date(today);
            limit.setDate(limit.getDate() -1);
            var next= new Date(today);
            next.setDate(next.getDate() + _rec-1);
            console.log(_rec+ " "+limitMin + " "+ lastDate);
            var save= true;
        
            if(limitMin>lastDate){
                console.log("mayor");
                limitMin.setDate(limitMin.getDate()-1);
                var r = confirm("Los tiempos del rango "+ lastDate.toISOString().slice(0, 10)+" - "+limitMin.toISOString().slice(0, 10)+ " no se va trasladar. \n ¿Desea Guardar la calendarización?");
                if (!r) {
                    save=false;
                }            
            }
            if(save){
                params = {
                    hour:_hour,
                    rec:_rec
                }
                makeCall('data/guardarCalendarizacion.php',params,function(err,res){
                    alert("Calendarización Actualizada");
                });
            }
        }
        
    });
}
```

Como se puede ver en las anteriores lineas antes de `setDate` coloqué un ternario para indicarle a las variables que se le sigen el valor de `null` al array pero quisiera que me ayudaran para saber cómo corregir y colocarle el ternario a la linea **`lastDate.setDate(lastDate.getDate()+1);`**

`getSchedule.php`

```
<?php 
require_once('data.php');
header('Content-Type: application/json; charset=UTF-8;');
//config
$dbhost = $hostname;
$dbname = $database;

//connection
$m = new MongoClient("mongodb://$dbhost");
$db = $m -> $dbname;

//selecting collection
$calendario = $db->ejecucion;

$result = $calendario->findOne();
if($result['recurrence']){
    $return = array(
        'recurrence'=>true,
        'rec'=>$result['period'],
        'hour'=>$result['hour'],
        'min'=>$result['min'],
        'lastExec'=>$result['last_execution'],
        'lastDay' =>$result['last_day']
    );
}
else{
    $return = array(
        'recurrence'=>false,
        'dayExec'=>$result['day_week'],
        'hour'=>$result['hour'],
        'min'=>$result['min'],
        'lastExec'=>$result['last_execution'],
        'firstExec'=>$result['first_execution'],
        'begin'=>$result['range']['start'],
        'end'=>$result['range']['end'],
        'lastDay' =>$result['last_day']
    );
}

echo json_encode($return, JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE);


?>
```

Comment: Posible duplicado de [cannot read property 'split' of null](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/279176/cannot-read-property-split-of-null)

Answer (score 0):

Los más probable es que el problema se deba a que no has tenido el debido cuidado con la  [precedencia de operaciones](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Operadores/Operator_Precedence). Coloca entre paréntesis la condición de cada uno de las operadores ternarios

Por ejemplo,

```
var arrayDate= _firstExec == null ? null: _firstExec.split('-');
```

cámbiala a

```
var arrayDate= (_firstExec == null) ? null: _firstExec.split('-');
```

Answer (score 0):

Te aconsejo que extraigas tu lógica de la fecha a una función para que tu código se más fácil de mantener y para que la puedas reutilizar no olvide el principio [DRY](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/No_te_repitas), por lo tanto lo te aconsejo lo siguiente:

```js
let lastMovedDay = '2019-07-16'

function convertirFecha(fecha){
  if(!fecha){
      return null;
  }
  let datosFecha = fecha.split('-');
  return new Date(datosFecha[0], datosFecha[1]-1, datosFecha[2]);
}

console.log(convertirFecha(lastMovedDay))
```

Por lo tanto que hice, realice una función que reciba un string que contiene una fecha en formato `yyyy-mm-dd`, se evalúa el contenido de la variable basándonos en  JavaScript debido a que usa el tipo coerción en contextos Booleanos; esto en otras palabras es el uso de [Falsy](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Glossary/Falsy), por lo tanto si el contenido es `null` retornara `null` de lo contrario retornar tu fecha esperada.

lo puedes implementar en tu codigo asi:

```
var arrayDate= _firstExec == null ? null: _firstExec.split('-');
```

lo cambias por

```
let arrayDate= convertirFecha(_firstExec);
```

Posdata: procura no utilizar declraciones de variables con la palabra reservada `var`, mejor empieza a implementar `let` o `const`, es un beneficio para ti mas adelante.

Comment: hola @Gdaimon muchas gracias por responder el comentario, te entendi un poco pero como podria cambiar mi codigo con el ejemplo que me diste? si me pudieras ayudar con mi codigo un poco te lo agradeceria

Comment: hola @Gdaimon usando este ejemplo tal cual me lo pasaste aqui podria hacer que cuando intente usar el split haya en la variable lastMovedDay? lo que sucede es que no pasa nada porque dice que esa variable esta nula y pues ese seria el error lastMovedDay.split('-')

Comment: @daniel rubio no entiendo lo que necesitas...?, se mas detallado por favor

Comment: si señor mira lo que sucede es lo siguiente como puedes ver la variable letMovedDay da nula es porque entra a getSchedule.php e intenta traer de base de datos lo cual no hace es decir esta vacia y es por eso que da ese error, yo quisiera saber que hago para que no de el error que podria hacer? como podria implementar o arreglar ese tema

Comment: perdon por no etiquetarlo en la pregunta de arriba

Comment: @daniel rubio sigo sin entender, `getSchedule.php` debe retornar `null`, es normal ese comportamiento?, si es normal que retorne `null` y quieres manejarlo, solamente utiliza la funcion en donde veas que el valor de la fecha puede llegar a estar `null`