# Error "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'value' of null"

Tags: javascript, asp.net

Estoy realizando mi primer formulario de registro en **ASP.NET** y utilizando tambien algo de **Javascript** estoy presentando el siguiente error al momento de registrar

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'value' of null

El siguiente es el código de mi javascript:

```
function f_submitForm() {
    $("#submit").css("display", "none");
    $("#load").css("display", "block");


    const auxPriorityInput = document.getElementById("ticketPriorityInput");
    const auxticketService = document.getElementById("ticketServiceInput");
    const auxticketSubService = document.getElementById("ticketSubServiceInput");
    const auxCategoryInput = document.getElementById("ticketCategoryInput");
    const auxticketOrigin = document.getElementById("ticketOriginInput");

    const form = new FormData();

    const ins = document.getElementById("file").files.length;
    for (let x = 0; x < ins; x++) {
        form.append("files[]", document.getElementById("file").files[x]);
    }

    form.append("ticketIdAppliInput", document.getElementById("ticketIdAppliInput").value);
    form.append("ticketNameAppliInput", document.getElementById("ticketNameAppliInput").value);
    form.append("ticketEmailAppliInput", document.getElementById("ticketEmailAppliInput").value);    
    form.append("ticketExtAppliInput", document.getElementById("ticketExtAppliInput").value);
    form.append("ticketPhoneAppliInput", document.getElementById("ticketPhoneAppliInput").value);
    form.append("ticketAreaAppliInput", document.getElementById("ticketAreaAppliInput").value);
    form.append("ticketLocationAppliInput", document.getElementById("ticketLocationAppliInput").value);
    form.append("ticketSubjectInput", document.getElementById("ticketSubjectInput").value);
    form.append("ticketDescrInput", document.getElementById("ticketDescrInput").value);
    form.append("ticketPriorityInput", auxPriorityInput.options[auxPriorityInput.selectedIndex].value);
    form.append("ticketServiceInput", auxticketService.options[auxticketService.selectedIndex].value);
    form.append("ticketSubServiceInput", auxticketSubService.options[auxticketSubService.selectedIndex].value);
    form.append("ticketCategoryInput", auxCategoryInput.options[auxCategoryInput.selectedIndex].value);
    form.append("ticketOriginInput", auxticketOrigin.options[auxticketOrigin.selectedIndex].value);
```

Mirando en la consola de mi navegador me encuentro con el error

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Exactamente en la propiedad de `ticketExtAppliInput` posiblemente el error se deba a que requiero hacer una validación con este campo cuando este vació se envié a guardar a el valor 0 por defecto, pero no estoy seguro de como hacerla, si esa puede ser la solución pueden indicarme como arreglarlo si no cual seria la solución correcta

**UPDATE:**

Tengo dos formularios, pero dependiendo de las variables de sesión, se cargan ciertos campos, `ticketExtAppliInput` tiene que ir tanto en uno como en otro, la diferencia es que en lo que necesito también va `ticketExtAppliInput` pero no se ingresa, necesito que se almacene por defecto. Valor "0"

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">

<div class="card-body">
                        <div class="mb-4">
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <label for="ticketExtAppliInput">Extensión:</label>
                                    <input step="1" id="ticketExtAppliInput" type="number" maxlength="6" oninput="if (this.value.length > this.maxLength) this.value = this.value.slice(0, this.maxLength);" name="extension" class="form-control form-control-user">
                                </div>
                        </div>
                </div>
```

Comment: Validaste que el elemento ticketExtAppliInput si exista en el DOM?, es posible que el document.getElementById no esté encontrando ese elemento, por lo tanto, intentar acceder al value te da error.

Comment: Posible duplicado de [¿Qué significa el error "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set/read property 'XXX' of undefined/null" y cómo solucionarlo?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/169194/qu%c3%a9-significa-el-error-uncaught-typeerror-cannot-set-read-property-xxx-of-u)

Comment: @JackNavaRow en la otra pregunta se llega al mismo error, ya la había consultado antes de preguntar, pero tienen objetivos diferentes, el objetivo mio es realizar la validación, saludos

Comment: el error es que el getElementById no lo consigues, por eso debes validar antes de buscar el elemento algo como `typeof document.getElementById("ticketIdAppliInput) !== 'undefined` si es true existe el elemento en el DOM y puedes acceder al value

Comment: @JackNavaRow Puedes agregarlo en una respuesta, probare si me funciona tu solucion

Comment: ¿Podías agregar tu HTML por favor?

Comment: @SebastianSalazar la respuesta esta explicada en la pregunta que marque como duplicado

Comment: @SebastianSalazar acabo de agregar una explicacion en el manejo del DOM

Comment: @fredyfx revisa nuevamente la pregunta ya agregue el HTML

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Puedes probar a hacer una validación en caso de que este vació asignarle el valor 0

```
function f_submitForm() {
$("#submit").css("display", "none");
$("#load").css("display", "block");

const auxPriorityInput = document.getElementById("ticketPriorityInput");
const auxticketService = document.getElementById("ticketServiceInput");
const auxticketSubService = document.getElementById("ticketSubServiceInput");
const auxCategoryInput = document.getElementById("ticketCategoryInput");
const auxticketOrigin = document.getElementById("ticketOriginInput");


const form = new FormData();

const ins = document.getElementById("file").files.length;
for (let x = 0; x < ins; x++) {
    form.append("files[]", document.getElementById("file").files[x]);
}

form.append("ticketIdAppliInput", document.getElementById("ticketIdAppliInput").value);
form.append("ticketNameAppliInput", document.getElementById("ticketNameAppliInput").value);
form.append("ticketEmailAppliInput", document.getElementById("ticketEmailAppliInput").value);    
if ($('ticketExtAppliInput').val() == "") {

    //le damos el valor de cero al no tener ningun valor
    document.getElementById("ticketExtAppliInput").value = "0";
} 
form.append("ticketPhoneAppliInput", document.getElementById("ticketPhoneAppliInput").value);
form.append("ticketAreaAppliInput", document.getElementById("ticketAreaAppliInput").value);
form.append("ticketLocationAppliInput", document.getElementById("ticketLocationAppliInput").value);
form.append("ticketSubjectInput", document.getElementById("ticketSubjectInput").value);
form.append("ticketDescrInput", document.getElementById("ticketDescrInput").value);
form.append("ticketPriorityInput", auxPriorityInput.options[auxPriorityInput.selectedIndex].value);
form.append("ticketServiceInput", auxticketService.options[auxticketService.selectedIndex].value);
form.append("ticketSubServiceInput", auxticketSubService.options[auxticketSubService.selectedIndex].value);
form.append("ticketCategoryInput", auxCategoryInput.options[auxCategoryInput.selectedIndex].value);
form.append("ticketOriginInput", auxticketOrigin.options[auxticketOrigin.selectedIndex].value);
```

Comment: Revisa tu respuesta tiene un error de sintaxis, dice que se espera ')'.

Comment: En que linea del codigo

Comment: En la condicion `if ($('#ticketExtAppliInput')val() == "") {`

Comment: ya realice el cambio faltaba un punto

Comment: Probé tu solución pero no me funciona sigue el mismo error del comienzo

Comment: modifique mi respuesta para poder validar si el elemento existe

Comment: [Continuemos el debate en el chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/97950/discussion-between-sebastian-salazar-and-johny-salazar).

Comment: Si la respuesta sirvió para tu solución te invito a que marques la respuesta como aceptada para que los futuros desarrolladores sepan que fue una solución correcta al problema y lo puedan implementar. Me alegra que te sirviera, Saludos !