# Problema: Cannot read property 'add' of null

Tags: html, jquery

Estoy trabajando con el slick, pero estoy teniendo un problema, la idea es que la misma función se aplique para el carrousel del home y para el carrousel de una ficha producto, para el home funciona bien, pero para la ficha ya no sirve, pero cuando le agrego una función aparte a la ficha producto me dice el error:

> **"Cannot read property 'add' of null"**

```
$('.listing-carousel').slick({
  dots: true,
  infinite: false,
  speed: 300,
  slidesToShow: 4,
  slidesToScroll: 4,
  responsive: [
    {
      breakpoint: 1024,
      settings: {
        slidesToShow: 3,
        slidesToScroll: 3,
        infinite: true,
        dots: true
      }
    },
    {
      breakpoint: 600,
      settings: {
        slidesToShow: 2,
        slidesToScroll: 2
      }
    },
    {
      breakpoint: 480,
      settings: {
        slidesToShow: 1,
        slidesToScroll: 1
      }
    }
  ]
});
```

```
<div class="listing-carousel">
  <!--contenido del carrousel-->
</div>
```

Ambos están bajo la misma clase, en otros proyectos me funciona bien, pero no sé por qué este es la excepción.

¿A qué se deberá?

Comment: tu JavaScript se carga al final de tu pagina HTML?, recuerda que si esta al inicio el DOM aun no se cargara y por alli puede ser el error

Comment: si, esta al final

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Duplicado de [¿Qué significa el error "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set/read property 'XXX' of undefined/null" y cómo solucionarlo?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/169194/qu%c3%a9-significa-el-error-uncaught-typeerror-cannot-set-read-property-xxx-of-u/169229#169229)  la respuesta se eliminara y la marcare como duplicado, le muesto al usuario el error

Acabo de agregar todas las librerias de slick, y me funciona sin problemas verifica que todos los archivos que necesita slick esten cargados

```js
$('.listing-carousel').slick({
  dots: true,
  infinite: false,
  speed: 300,
  slidesToShow: 4,
  slidesToScroll: 4,
  responsive: [
    {
      breakpoint: 1024,
      settings: {
        slidesToShow: 3,
        slidesToScroll: 3,
        infinite: true,
        dots: true
      }
    },
    {
      breakpoint: 600,
      settings: {
        slidesToShow: 2,
        slidesToScroll: 2
      }
    },
    {
      breakpoint: 480,
      settings: {
        slidesToShow: 1,
        slidesToScroll: 1
      }
    }
  ]
});
```

```html
<!-- Add the slick-theme.css if you want default styling -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="//cdn.jsdelivr.net/gh/kenwheeler/slick@1.8.1/slick/slick.css"/>
    <!-- Add the slick-theme.css if you want default styling -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="//cdn.jsdelivr.net/gh/kenwheeler/slick@1.8.1/slick/slick-theme.css"/>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="//cdn.jsdelivr.net/gh/kenwheeler/slick@1.8.1/slick/slick.min.js"></script>


    <div class="listing-carousel">
      <div><img src="https://dummyimage.com/200x200/e3e3e3/000000.jpg"/></div>
      <div><img src="https://dummyimage.com/200x200/000/000000.jpg"/></div>
      <div><img src="https://dummyimage.com/200x200/e3e3e3/000000.jpg"/></div>
      <div><img src="https://dummyimage.com/200x200/000/000000.jpg"/></div>
      <div><img src="https://dummyimage.com/200x200/e3e3e3/000000.jpg"/></div>
      <div><img src="https://dummyimage.com/200x200/000/000000.jpg"/></div>
    </div>
        <div class="listing-carousel">
      <div><img src="https://dummyimage.com/100x100/e3e3e3/000000.jpg"/></div>
      <div><img src="https://dummyimage.com/100x100/000/000000.jpg"/></div>
      <div><img src="https://dummyimage.com/100x100/e3e3e3/000000.jpg"/></div>
      <div><img src="https://dummyimage.com/100x100/000/000000.jpg"/></div>
      <div><img src="https://dummyimage.com/100x100/e3e3e3/000000.jpg"/></div>
      <div><img src="https://dummyimage.com/100x100/000/000000.jpg"/></div>
    </div>
```

Comment: si, tengo las librerías, ya que como indique en la pregunta, funciona en el home, pero no en el producto

Comment: entonces estas reescribiendo la clases `listing-carousel` que tal si accedes por id, o le cambias el nombre a la clase?

Comment: es que la idea es hacer funcionar 2 carruseles con la misma función, por eso le coloque la misma clase

Comment: acabo de hacer lo mismo y me funciona!, mira la respuesta

Comment: gracias por aceptar, pero esta pregunta es duplicada

Comment: si quieres dale +1 a la respuesta original, explica mas en detalle este tipo de errores y como controlarlos