# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property '0' of undefined JavaScript

Tags: javascript

He intentado acceder a una de las propiedades de un array de objetos para poder realizar ciertas comprobaciones. Pero cuando intento acceder a él me muestra el siguiente error:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

función:

```
function selectPercentage (element,number) {

    let movementFound = false;
    let percentageMatch = 0;

    while(movementFound == false) {

            let x = 0;

            if(number < SHIP_DATA[element].percentage[x]) {
                    percentageMatch = x;
                    movementFound = true;

            } else { x++ }


    }

    return(percentageMatch);
}
```

Array de objetos:

```
const SHIP_DATA = [

    {
            ship: 'Juan Sebastían el Cano',
            advantage: 5,
            normal: 3,
            disadvantage: -4,
            porcentaje : [25,65,100]
    },
    {
            ship: 'Carabela Santa María',
            advantage: 5,
            normal: 4,
            disadvantage: -3,
            percentage: [33,66,100]
    },
    {
            ship: 'Goleta salvar el mundo',
            advantage: 10,
            normal: 3,
            disadvantage: 0,
            percentage: [40,70,100]
    }
 ]
```

En la primera iteración del bucle en la posición 0 de *SHIP_DATA* debería poder acceder al valor '25', en cambio me devuelve undefined. Accedo a este mismo array y a sus otras propiedades sin ningún tipo de problema.

Agradecería cualquier documentación útil o correción, muchas gracias.

Comment: a veces usas `porcentaje` y otras `percentage`,  en donde existe una no existe la otra, esta `undefined`.

Comment: quita [X] ya que ya accediste al array ahora solo accedes a la propiedad

Comment: Me has cazado la errata en 10 segundos y llevo 30 minutos mirando el código. Muchísimas gracias.

Comment: si te funciono ? y a te dejo la respuesta

Comment: Posible duplicado de [¿Qué significa el error "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set/read property 'XXX' of undefined/null" y cómo solucionarlo?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/169194/qu%c3%a9-significa-el-error-uncaught-typeerror-cannot-set-read-property-xxx-of-u)

Answer (score 1):

tu error esta la siguiente linea la debes modificar

```
SHIP_DATA[element].percentage[x]
```

Ya que ya estas accediendo a la posicion del **array** ,ahora solo tendrías que acceder a la propiedad del objeto así:

```
SHIP_DATA[element].percentage
```

Ahora accedes al valor de la posicion de esta forma

```
var percenArray = SHIP_DATA[element].percentage;

percenArray.forEach((x, y) => { // (y) es el index del array y (X) el valor
     if(number < y) {
        percentageMatch = x;
        movementFound = true;
     } 
});
```

Comment: que pasa con `SHIP_DATA[0].percentage` ? además que sentido tendría evaluar `number < [33,66,100]`

Comment: Emeeus , el solo preguntaba por el error que no podia acceder a la propiedad, lo que tendria que hacer ahora es recorrer cada propiedad

Answer (score 0):

Ojo que tambien el elemento percentage no existe para el array[0] segun como lo muestras

```
        ship: 'Juan Sebastían el Cano',
        advantage: 5,
        normal: 3,
        disadvantage: -4,
        >>porcentaje : [25,65,100]
```

eso hace que tambien te genere un invalid por que como estas buscando no existe