# Angular 7+ Cannot read property 'control' of undefined

Tags: angular, typescript

Buenos días querría saber si alguien es tan amable de decirme porque en mi formulario me da el siguiente error: Cannot read property 'control' of undefined, siempre que agrego un ui-input-text a mi form.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

En mi clase Ts. Tengo un objeto.

```
public contact = { name: '' };
```

Muchas Gracias de antemano o por cualquier respuesta.

Comment: Hola, bienvenida a [es.so]. Te invito a leer [ask] y [mcve]. Además puedes realizar el [tour] para informarte de cómo funciona el sitio. Tu pregunta es muy amplia y sin ver el código mínimo de lo que intentas hacer es difícil ayudarte. Por otro lado, es mejor que copies y pegues el código en lugar de subir imagenes. Saludos

Comment: Bienvenida, sería más sencillo si en vez de poner una imagen pegases directamente el código.
Es importante realizar preguntas en el sitio en base a el documento [Cómo preguntar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). No olvides realizar el [recorrido](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour) del sitio para conocer su funcionamiento básico, saludos.

Comment: El html está ligado al component.ts, necesitaríamos verlo ..

Comment: Posible duplicado de [¿Qué significa el error "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set/read property 'XXX' of undefined/null" y cómo solucionarlo?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/169194/qu%c3%a9-significa-el-error-uncaught-typeerror-cannot-set-read-property-xxx-of-u)

Comment: tiene pinta de que no has creado un formGroup en tu componente

Comment: Muchas gracias Pablo. Era exactamente eso!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Para definir un formulario deberías utilizar un FormGroup.

```
const logiForm = new FormGroup({
  username: new FormControl(),
  pass: new FormControl(),
});
```

Aqui puedes encontrar más información respecto a los formularios en angular.
https://codingpotions.com/angular-formularios

Comment: Muchas gracias Jairo. Era justo eso!