# ¿Cómo solucionar al error "TypeError: Cannot read property of undefined" ? (Angular)

Tags: angular, typescript, spring-boot

Me gustaría saber cuál es la falla que estoy teniendo en mi código. El error que me arroja cuando quiero cargar la tabla con todos los datos de la base es el de: **Cannot read property 'denominacion' of undefined**

A continuación mostraré primero el código con su lógica que se necesita para armar la tabla, y luego esta última:

**Clases**

```
export interface ArticuloManufacturado {

id?: number;
denominacion?: string;
tiempoDePreparacion?: number;
imagen?: string;
precioVenta?: number;

rubroGeneral?: RubroGeneral;
detalles?: ArticuloManufacturadoDetalle[];
```

}

```
export interface RubroGeneral {

id?: number;
denominacion?: string;
```

}

```
export interface ArticuloManufacturadoDetalle {

id?: number;
cantidad?: number;
articuloInsumo?: ArticulosInsumos;
```

}

```
export interface ArticulosInsumos {

id?: number;
denominacion?: string;
```

}

**Lógica empleada**

```
export class ArticulosmanufacturadosComponent implements OnInit {

manufacturados: ArticuloManufacturado[];

constructor(private service: ArticulomanufacturadoService) { }

ngOnInit(): void {
this.getManufacturados();
}

getManufacturados() {
this.service.getManufacturados().subscribe(res => {
  this.manufacturados = res;
  //console.log(res)
    })
  }
}
```

**TABLA**

```
<div class="container">
<table class="table table-bordered table-striped">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>ID</th>
            <th>Denominacion</th>
            <th>Tiempo de preparación</th>
            <th>Imágen</th>
            <th>Precio-Venta</th>
            <th>Rubro-General</th>
            <th>Detalles</th>
            <th>Acciones</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr *ngFor="let manufacturado of manufacturados">
            <td><span>{{manufacturado.id}}</span></td>
            <td><span>{{manufacturado.denominacion}}</span></td>
            <td><span>{{manufacturado.tiempoDePreparacion}}</span></td>
            <td><span>{{manufacturado.imagen}}</span></td>
            <td><span>{{manufacturado.precioVenta}}</span></td>
            <td><span>{{manufacturado.rubroGeneral.denominacion}}</span></td>
            <td>
                <ul>
                     <li *ngFor="let item of manufacturado.detalles">
                         {{item.cantidad}} - {{item.articuloInsumo.denominacion}}
                     </li>
                </ul>
            </td>
            <td>
                <button class="btn btn-sm btn-info">
                    <i class="fa fa-search"></i>Detalles</button>
                <button class="btn btn-sm btn-warning">
                    <i class="fa fa-edit"></i>Editar</button>
                <button class="btn btn-sm btn-danger">
                    <i class="fa fa-remove"></i>Eliminar</button>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Imagen de lo que se me devuelve por consola al ejecutar un console.log con la respuesta:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Los datos me los trae casi todos, los que no son los del segundo ciclo 'ngFor. Que son los pertenecientes a los detalles. Más específicamente el de {{item.articuloInsumo.denominacion}}

Comment: A mi parecer no le está llegando el dato a la variable articuloInsumo por lo tanto cuando la aplicación quiere leer un atributo de un undefined se rompe.
Cualquier ayuda que necesite con gusto le ayudaré.
La variable en la barra de herramientas de su navegador en network se llama compararía.

Comment: ya haz hecho console.log de la respuesta para comprobar que te llega toda la información desde la api?

Comment: Hola, si. Me trae toda la información. Sinceramente no se que puede ser :(

Comment: Si puedes, pon una imagen o copia la respuesta del api con console.log, talvez el error esta allí

Comment: Ahí lo hice, si puedes chequearlo te lo agradecería un montón !

Comment: item.articuloInsumo.denominacion no existe. el que veo es item.articulo.denominacion

Comment: Dios mío, tenés razón. Que estúpido me siento, muchísimas gracias por la ayuda! Hay te recompenso con puntos!

Comment: ¿Responde esto a tu pregunta? [¿Qué significa el error "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set/read properties of undefined/null" y cómo solucionarlo?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/169194/qu%c3%a9-significa-el-error-uncaught-typeerror-cannot-set-read-properties-of-undef)

Answer (score 0):

- Al parecer la respuesta es sencilla: tu arreglo llamado
  manufacturados no ha sido inicializado.
- manufacturados: ArticuloManufacturado[]; ===> así está.
- manufacturados: ArticuloManufacturado[] = []; ====> así debe estar.

Answer (score 0):

Esto es debido a que primero se carga tu html antes de que los valores a recorrer sean asignados a la propiedad, para solucionar agrega un 'ngIf' en tu tabla para que no muestre hasta que este cargado tu propiedad con los datos a recorrer:
la propiedad a crear es 'load'

.html:

```
<div class="container">
<table *ngIf="load" class="table table-bordered table-striped">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>ID</th>
            <th>Denominacion</th>
            <th>Tiempo de preparación</th>
            <th>Imágen</th>
            <th>Precio-Venta</th>
            <th>Rubro-General</th>
            <th>Detalles</th>
            <th>Acciones</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr *ngFor="let manufacturado of manufacturados">
            <td><span>{{manufacturado.id}}</span></td>
            <td><span>{{manufacturado.denominacion}}</span></td>
            <td><span>{{manufacturado.tiempoDePreparacion}}</span></td>
            <td><span>{{manufacturado.imagen}}</span></td>
            <td><span>{{manufacturado.precioVenta}}</span></td>
            <td><span>{{manufacturado.rubroGeneral.denominacion}}</span></td>
            <td>
                <ul>
                     <li *ngFor="let item of manufacturado.detalles">
                         {{item.cantidad}} - {{item.articuloInsumo.denominacion}}
                     </li>
                </ul>
            </td>
            <td>
                <button class="btn btn-sm btn-info">
                    <i class="fa fa-search"></i>Detalles</button>
                <button class="btn btn-sm btn-warning">
                    <i class="fa fa-edit"></i>Editar</button>
                <button class="btn btn-sm btn-danger">
                    <i class="fa fa-remove"></i>Eliminar</button>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

typeScript:

```
export class ArticulosmanufacturadosComponent implements OnInit {

manufacturados: ArticuloManufacturado[];
load: boolean;

constructor(private service: ArticulomanufacturadoService) { }

ngOnInit(): void {
this.getManufacturados();
}

getManufacturados() {
this.service.getManufacturados().subscribe(res => {
  this.manufacturados = res;
  load = true;
  //console.log(res)
    })
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Coloca el `*ngIf` en el `tbody` para que lo imprima sólo si viene `true`:

```
<tbody *ngIf="manufacturado">
```