# Como puedo resolver este error? Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot set property 'innerHTML' of null

Tags: get

ESTE ES MI index.js, es aqui donde me da el error al abrir en el navegador, no me pinta los contactos de la agenda web.

```
function getDatos(){
    fetch("http://www.raydelto.org/agenda.php").then(
        function(captura){
            return captura.json();
        }
    ).then(
        function(captura)
        {
           var txtNombre = document.getElementById("txtNombre");
           var txtApellido = document.getElementById("txtApellido");
           var txtTelefono = document.getElementById("txtTelefono");
            txtNombre.innerHTML= captura[1].nombre;
            txtApellido.innerHTML = captura[1].apellido;
            txtTelefono.innerHTML = captura[1].telefono;
        }
    )
}
```

lo que busco hacer con esto es obtener los contactos guardados en la agenda, solo estoy haciendo una prueba con algunos contactos pero luego quiero invocar la misma url mediante el metodo POST de HTTP y enviando un cuerpo JSON con los campos nombre, apellido , telefono agregar nuevos contactos a la agenda, esto ultimo mencionado no se como hacerlo. cualquier ayuda seria bien agradecida

ESTE ES EL index.html

```
<html>  
    <head>  
        <title> Agenda de Contactos</title>
        <script src = "js/index.js"></script>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <link rel="stylesheet"href="css/index.css">
    </head>
    <body>
        <body onload="getDatos()">
            <h1>Agenda Multicapas</h1>

            <div class="contacto">
                <div class ="fila">
                    <div class="titulo">Nombre:</div>
                    <div class="valor id="txtNombre"></div>
                </div>
                 <div class="fila">
                    <div class="titulo">Apellido:</div>
                <div class="valor" id="txtApellido"></div>
                 </div>
                

                <div class="fila">
                    <div class="titulo">Telefono:</div>
                <div class="valor" id="txtTelefono"></div>
                 </div>    
                </div>
        </body>  
</html>
```

Y ESTE ES EL CSS

```
.contacto
{
    size: 15px;
    background-color: #ffe4c4;
    border-radius: 12%;
    padding: 18px;
}
.titulo
{
    font-weight: bold;
    padding-bottom: 18px;
    padding-right: 30px;
}

.valor
{
    font-weight: 90%;;

}
.fila{
    display: flex;
}
```

Comment: Podrías mostrar el html ? Talvez estas escribiendo mal un id

Comment: ¿Responde esto a tu pregunta? [¿Qué significa el error "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set/read property 'XXX' of undefined/null" y cómo solucionarlo?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/169194/qu%c3%a9-significa-el-error-uncaught-typeerror-cannot-set-read-property-xxx-of-u)

Comment: @MatiasManzanzani copie el html , miralo arriba

Comment: Tienes un error en tu elemento, por eso no reconoce el id: `<div class="valor id="txtNombre"></div>` olvidaste cerrar la comilla de class, intenta corrigiéndolo así: **`<div class="valor" id="txtNombre"></div>`**

Comment: @A.Cedano gracias, ese era el error