# ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'push' of undefined

Tags: angular, typescript

Buenas tardes Estimados,

Les presento este error que estoy teniendo intentar realizar un push a un objeto que obtengo en un arreglo que estoy desestructurando y poder mostrarlo en HTML.

La finalidad del mismo es poder mostrar directamente en un html el arreglo de mensajes que obtengo al insertarlos en un grupo particular.

Aqui el componente.

Modal-Home-detail.ts

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import {Router, ActivatedRoute, Params} from '@angular/router';
import {LoginService } from '../../login/login.service';
import {HomeService } from '../../home/home.service';
import {EventsService } from '../../events/events.service';


import {GroupsSchema} from '../../../models/group';
import { UserSchema } from 'src/app/models/user-model';
import { MessageSchema } from 'src/app/models/message';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-modal-home-detail',
  templateUrl: './modal-home-detail.page.html',
  styleUrls: ['./modal-home-detail.page.scss'],
  providers:[ LoginService, HomeService, EventsService ]
})

export class ModalHomeDetailPage implements OnInit {

  public user : Array <UserSchema>;
  public identity;
  public token;
  public status;
  public group: GroupsSchema[];
  public rescueMsg:[];
  

  constructor( private loginService : LoginService,
              private homeService: HomeService,
              private eventsServce: EventsService,
              private _router :Router,
              private _route :ActivatedRoute,
  ) { 
    this.identity=this.loginService.getIdentity();
    this.token=this.loginService.getToken();
 
  }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.getGroup();
  }

  getGroup(){
    this._route.params.subscribe(params =>{
      let id = params['id'];

      this.eventsServce.getGroupHome(id,this.token).subscribe(
        response =>{
          if(response.group){
            this.group=response.group; 
            console.log(this.group);

           // for ( const messageDetails in this.group.messages) { console.log(messageDetails)}; 

           
          this.group.messages.forEach(obj => {
            Object.entries(obj).forEach(([key, value]) => {
                console.log(`${key} ${value}`);
                this.rescueMsg.push(obj[key]);
                
            });

            console.log('-------------------');
          });



          }else{
            this._router.navigate(['/main/tabs/home']);
          }
        },
        error =>{
          console.log(error);
        }
      );
  });
}
```

Al realizar un console.log del response.group, tengo los siguientes datos que me llegan desde un backend que contienen documentos embebidos

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

```
core.js:4197 ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'push' of undefined
    at modal-home-detail.page.ts:60
    at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)
    at modal-home-detail.page.ts:58
    at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)
    at SafeSubscriber._next (modal-home-detail.page.ts:57)
    at SafeSubscriber.__tryOrUnsub (Subscriber.js:183)
    at SafeSubscriber.next (Subscriber.js:122)
    at Subscriber._next (Subscriber.js:72)
    at Subscriber.next (Subscriber.js:49)
    at MapSubscriber._next (map.js:35)
```

Deseo poder obtener las propiedades y sus valores para mostrarlos en el HTML

```
<ion-header>
  <ion-toolbar>
    <ion-title> //RESULTADO ERROR//{{this.messagesContent}} </ion-title>
  </ion-toolbar>
</ion-header>

<ion-content>

</ion-content>
```

Comment: ¿En qué momento se inicializa el arreglo rescueMsg?, No puedes usar una variable sin inicializar.

Comment: ¿Responde esto a tu pregunta? [¿Qué significa el error "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set/read property 'XXX' of undefined/null" y cómo solucionarlo?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/169194/qu%c3%a9-significa-el-error-uncaught-typeerror-cannot-set-read-property-xxx-of-u)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Indagando un poco sobre el errror, me funciono declarar un nuevo arreglo de group. Les muestro como:

```
  public identity;
  public token;
  public status;
  public user : UserSchema[];
  public group: GroupsSchema;
  public message: MessageSchema;
  public rescueMsg:[];
  public messages;
  

  constructor( private loginService : LoginService,
              private homeService: HomeService,
              private eventsServce: EventsService,
              private _router :Router,
              private _route :ActivatedRoute,
  ) { 
    this.identity=this.loginService.getIdentity();
    this.token=this.loginService.getToken();
    this.message = new MessageSchema();
    this.group = new GroupsSchema("","","","","")


getGroup(){
    this._route.params.subscribe(params =>{
      let id = params['id'];

      this.homeService.getGroupHome(id,this.token).subscribe(
        response =>{
          if(response.group){
            this.group=response.group; 
            console.log(response.group.messsages)
           // for ( const messageDetails in this.group.messages) { console.log(messageDetails)}; 
          /*
          this.group.messages.forEach(obj => {
            Object.entries(obj).forEach(([key, value]) => {
                console.log(`${key} ${value}`);
                //this.rescueMsg.push(); 
            });
            console.log('-------------------');
          });
*/
          }else{
            this._router.navigate(['/main/tabs/home']);
          }
        },
        error =>{
          console.log(error);
        }
      );
  });
}

addMesssage(form){
 this.homeService.addMessage(this.token, this.message, this.group._id).subscribe(
   response=>{
     console.log(this.token);
     console.log(this.message);
     console.log(this.group._id);

    if(!response.group){;
      this.status='error'
      console.log(response.group);
      
    }else {
      this.status ="success";
      this.group = response.group;
      form.reset();
      console.log(this.group.messages);
    }
   },
   error =>{
     this.status ='error';
    console.log(error);
   }
 );
}
```

Con esto pude resolver el error

Saludos!

Answer (score 4):

Debes de inicializar tus arreglos. Por defecto están como `undefined` y este no contiene la propiedad `push`.

```js
 public user : Array <UserSchema> = [] //Aqui;
  public identity;
  public token;
  public status;
  public group: GroupsSchema[] = [];
  public rescueMsg:[] = [];
```