# ¿Cómo lograr guardar de esta manera estos datos en la base de datos? (Spring + Angular)

Tags: angular, typescript, spring-boot

He estado realizando un curso de **Udemy** de **FullStack** (Spring + Angular), cuyo autor es **'Chad Derby'**. En este curso si se siguen sus videos, se logra hacer un pequeño **ecommerce**.

El problema que tengo es que cuando se da en **'Purchase'** para poder realizar la orden y de esta manera guardar los datos en la base se guardan de una manera que no es la que me gustaría, para graficar mejor esto, muestro estas **imágenes** de los datos en la **base**:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Me gustaría que nos enfoquemos en la tabla **'orders_item'**, para lograr la estructura de la misma, Chad Derby desarrolló esta entidad:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "order_items")
@Getter
@Setter
public class OrderItem {

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
@Column(name = "id")
private Long id;

@Column(name = "image_url")
private String imageUrl;

@Column(name = "quantity")
private int quantity;

@Column(name = "unit_price")
private BigDecimal unitPrice;

@Column(name = "product_id")
private Long productId;

@ManyToOne
@JoinColumn(name = "order_id")
private Order order;
}
```

Lo que quisiera hacer es que la estructura de la tabla sea la siguiente:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "order_items")
@Getter
@Setter
public class OrderItem {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "id")
    private Long id;

    @Column(name = "image_url")
    private String imageUrl;

    @Column(name = "quantity")
    private int quantity;

    @Column(name = "unit_price")
    private BigDecimal unitPrice;

    @ManyToOne()
    @JoinColumn(name = "product_id")
    private Product product;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "order_id")
    private Order order;
    }
```

De esta manera la tabla en la base de datos quedaría de la siguiente manera:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Puedo realizar la orden desde el **backend**, utilizando **Postman**. Lo que no puedo es realizarla desde el **frontend**. A continuación dejaré la lógica:

Clases en **typescript** involucradas:

```
export class Order {

    totalQuantity: number;
    totalPrice: number;
}

export class CartItem {

    id: string;
    name: string;
    imageUrl: string;
    unitPrice: number;

    quantity: number;

    constructor(product: Product) {
        this.id = product.id;
        this.name = product.name;
        this.imageUrl = product.imageUrl;
        this.unitPrice = product.unitPrice;
        this.quantity = 1;
    }
}

export class OrderItem {

    imageUrl: string;
    unitPrice: number;
    quantity: number;
    product: Product;
    productId: string;

    constructor(cartItem: CartItem) {
        
      this.imageUrl = cartItem.imageUrl;
      this.quantity = cartItem.quantity;
      this.unitPrice = cartItem.unitPrice;
      this.productId = cartItem.id;
      this.product.id = this.productId; // Esta es la prueba que realicé.
    }
}
```

Ahora, la lógica del componente **'Checkout'**:

```
onSubmit() {
    console.log("Handling the submit button");
    if (this.checkoutFormGroup.invalid) { // Si es inválido...
      this.checkoutFormGroup.markAllAsTouched(); // Tocar todos los campos activa la visualización de 
      los mensajes de error.
      return;
    }

    // Preparar una orden.
    let order = new Order();
    order.totalPrice = this.totalPrice;
    order.totalQuantity = this.totalQuantity;

    // Obtener los items del Carro.
    const cartItems = this.cartService.cartItems; // En el service, está esta propiedad -> cartItems: 
    CartItem[] = [];

    // Crear items de la orden desde nuestro CartItem.
    let orderItems: OrderItem[] = cartItems.map(tempCartItem => new OrderItem(tempCartItem));
    console.log(orderItems[0].productId); // Puedo acceder al valor del producto que se 'tendría que 
    guardar'.

    // Preparar el 'purchase'.
    let purchase = new Purchase();

    // Popular purchase - customer.
    purchase.customer = this.checkoutFormGroup.controls['customer'].value;

    // Popular purchase - shipping address.
    purchase.shippingAddress = this.checkoutFormGroup.controls['shippingAddress'].value;
    const shippingState: State = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(purchase.shippingAddress.state));
    const shippingCountry: Country = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(purchase.shippingAddress.country));
    purchase.shippingAddress.state = shippingState.name;
    purchase.shippingAddress.country = shippingCountry.name;

    // Popular purchase - billing address.
    purchase.billingAddress = this.checkoutFormGroup.controls['billingAddress'].value;
    const billingState: State = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(purchase.billingAddress.state));
    const billingCountry: Country = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(purchase.billingAddress.country));
    purchase.billingAddress.state = billingState.name;
    purchase.billingAddress.country = billingCountry.name;

    // Popular purchase - order y orderItems.
    purchase.order = order;
    purchase.orderItems = orderItems;

    // Llamar a nuestra API REST a través de CheckoutService.
    this.checkoutService.placeOrder(purchase).subscribe(
      {
        next: response => {
          alert(`Your order has been received.\nOrder tracking number: 
          ${response.orderTrackingNumber}`)
          // Resetear el Carro.
          this.resetCart();
        },
        error: err => {
          alert(`There was an error: ${err.message}`);
        }
      }
    )
  }
```

Cuando hago click en **Submit** me tira error **'"ERROR TypeError: Cannot set property 'id' of undefined"'**.

Desde ya agradezco muchísimo a quien me pueda ayudar u orientar, si necesitan ver el **repositorio completo** se los dejo a continuación en el link:

**Backend** -> https://github.com/justanuser22/Backend

**Frontend** -> https://github.com/justanuser22/Frontend

Comment: esas líneas con `JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(...))` huelen MUY mal.

Comment: ¿Responde esto a tu pregunta? [¿Qué significa el error "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set/read property 'XXX' of undefined/null" y cómo solucionarlo?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/169194/qu%c3%a9-significa-el-error-uncaught-typeerror-cannot-set-read-property-xxx-of-u)

Answer (score 1):

Tienes el siguiente código:

```
export class OrderItem {

    imageUrl: string;
    unitPrice: number;
    quantity: number;
    product: Product;
    productId: string;

    constructor(cartItem: CartItem) {
        
      this.imageUrl = cartItem.imageUrl;
      this.quantity = cartItem.quantity;
      this.unitPrice = cartItem.unitPrice;
      this.productId = cartItem.id;
      this.product.id = this.productId; // Esta es la prueba que realicé.
    }
}
```

La propiedad `this.product` nunca es inicializada, por lo que vale `undefined`.
Por tanto, estás intentando definir un `id` a un valor undefined.

Comment: Probé lo que escribiste y funcionó, muchas gracias!