# Como solucionar "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'split' of null"

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, ajax

Tengo dos formularios en los cuales cargo documentos al servidor por medio de un Webservice .asmx en donde he usado Jquery y AJAX para el código del lado del cliente y C# para el lado del servicio, ambos formularios utilizan el mismo Webservice.

Para el primer formulario cargo el documento sin problema y luego puedo verlo en el servidor, pero para el segundo formulario también se carga sin problema pero ahí algo que me causa conflicto y es en la consola el siguiente mensaje de error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'split' of null
    at HTMLButtonElement.<anonymous> (CargaCV.js:26)
    at HTMLButtonElement.dispatch (jquery.min.js:2)
    at HTMLButtonElement.y.handle (jquery.min.js:2)
```

Este es el código html de mi primer formulario

```
<div class="form-group">
       <label for="recipient-name" class="col-form-label">Adjunta tu CV</label>
       <input type="file" id="FileUpload1" accept="application/pdf" />
</div>

<div class="modal-footer">
       <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Cerrar</button>
       <button id="btnSave" type="button" class="Enviar">Enviar</button>
</div>
```

El siguiente es la función JQuery de mi primer formulario.

**CargaCV.js**

```
$(function () {
    var reader = new FileReader();
    var fileName;
    $('[id*=FileUpload1]').change(function () {
        if (typeof (FileReader) != "undefined") {
            var regex = /(.pdf)/;                
            $($(this)[0].files).each(function () {
                var file = $(this);
                if (regex.test(file[0].name.toLowerCase())) {
                    fileName = file[0].name;
                    reader.readAsDataURL(file[0]);
                } else {
                    alert(file[0].name + " no es un formato de archivo valido.");
                    return false;
                }
            });
        } else {
            alert("This browser does not support HTML5 FileReader.");
        }
    });

    $("[id*=btnSave]").click(function () {
        var byteData = reader.result;

        byteData = byteData.split(';')[1].replace("base64,", "");

        var obj = {};
        obj.Data = byteData;
        obj.Name = fileName;
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "../FileUpload.asmx/UploadFile",
            data: '{fileData : ' + JSON.stringify(obj) + ' }',
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            dataType: "json",
            success: function (r) {
                setTimeout(EnviarInformacion(fileName), 20000)                  
            },
            error: function (r) {
                alert(r.responseText);
            },
            failure: function (r) {
                alert(r.responseText);
            }
        });
        return false;
    });    
});
```

Ahora vamos con el código del segundo formulario aquí va el html:

```
<div class="form-group">
    <label for="recipient-name" class="col-form-label">Adjunta tu CV</label>
    <input type="file" value="upload" id="FileUpload2" accept="application/pdf" />
</div>

<div class="modal-footer">
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Cerrar</button>
    <button id="btnSave2" type="button" class="Enviar">Enviar</button>
</div>
```

Código JQuery de mi segundo formulario:

**CargaCV2.js**

```
$(function () {

    var reader1 = new FileReader();
    var fileName1;
    $('[id*=FileUpload2]').change(function () {
        if (typeof (FileReader) != "undefined") {
            var regex = /(.pdf)/;          
            $($(this)[0].files).each(function () {
                var file = $(this);
                if (regex.test(file[0].name.toLowerCase())) {
                    fileName1 = file[0].name;
                    reader1.readAsDataURL(file[0]);
                } else {
                    alert(file[0].name + " no es un formato de archivo valido.");
                    return false;
                }
            });
        } else {
            alert("This browser does not support HTML5 FileReader.");
        }
    });



    $("[id*=btnSave2]").click(function () {
        var byteData = reader1.result;

        byteData = byteData.split(';')[1].replace("base64,", "");

        var obj = {};
        obj.Data = byteData;
        obj.Name = fileName1;
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "../FileUpload.asmx/UploadFile",
            data: '{fileData : ' + JSON.stringify(obj) + ' }',
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            dataType: "json",
            success: function (r) {
                setTimeout(EnviarInformacionRelacionada(fileName1), 30000)               
            },
            error: function (r) {
                alert(r.responseText);
            },
            failure: function (r) {
                alert(r.responseText);
            }
        });
        return false;
    });
});
```

Dándole un poco de seguimiento al mensaje de la consola me lo marca exactamente en la línea 26 del archivo **CargaCV.js**, lo mas raro es que el error es en el archivo **CargaCV.js** cuando estoy subiendo el archivo desde el formulario 2 el cual esta haciendo referencia a **CargaCV2.js**, es como si algo del archivo **CargaCV.js** estuviera haciendo referencia a las acciones del formulario 2.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

**Actualización:**

Posiblemente [esto](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/169194/qu%C3%A9-significa-el-error-uncaught-typeerror-cannot-set-read-property-xxx-of-u) responda a mi pregunta

Pero aquí no especifica que sea la propiedad `split`.

Junto a mi pregunta explico a detalle que son dos formularios que utilizo ambos con funciones iguales con sus respectivos `ID`.

Vuelvo y reitero que con el primer formulario no me genera ninguna excepción en consola y con el segundo si me la genera.

Comment: ¿Responde esto a tu pregunta? [¿Qué significa el error "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set/read property 'XXX' of undefined/null" y cómo solucionarlo?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/169194/qu%c3%a9-significa-el-error-uncaught-typeerror-cannot-set-read-property-xxx-of-u)

Answer (score 0):

Talvez tu  byteData.split(';')[1] devuelva  null  y estas haciendo un remplace.
seria mejor validar  que dato te devuelve console.log(byteData.split(';')) y valida que tenga [1]

Comment: Porque cuando subo mi archivo por medio del formulario 1 no me genera ningún error en consola y cuando lo hago con el formulario 2 me genera el error de mi pregunta pero este hace referencia al archivo javascript del formulario 1 ?