# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'className' of null

Tags: javascript, html

*Hola, buenas.
(Perdón si no doy mucha información, recién estoy comenzando)
Les comento: Me sale error cuando intento traer la clase 'active' que se le fue asignada:*
**Línea del error:**

```
document.querySelector(propTabs.contenido_activo).className = 'active';
```

Mi estructura html:

```
<section class="menu-platos" id="nuestro_menu">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="titulo-seccion">
                <h2>Platos principales</h2>
            </div>

            <div class="contenedor-menu">
                <ul id="encabezado_menu" class="encabezado">
                    <li><a href="#postres">Platos</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#cafes">Bebidas</a></li>
                </ul>
                <div class="contenido" id="contenido_menu">

                    <!-- Menú Comida -->

                    <div id="comida">

                        <!-- Plato 1 -->
                        <div class="item">
                            <div class="col izq">
                                <h3>Pollo a la brasa</h3>
                                <p>Pollo asado al carbón y papas fritas</p>
                            </div>
                            <div class="col der">
                                <p class="precio">S/. 14.80</p>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <!-- Plato 2 -->
                        <div class="item">
                            <div class="col izq">
                                <h3>Lomo Saltado</h3>
                                <p>Carned de res, arroz cocido y papas fritas</p>
                            </div>
                            <div class="col der">
                                <p class="precio">S/. 12.80</p>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <!-- Plato 3 -->
                        <div class="item">
                            <div class="col izq">
                                <h3>Causa Rellena</h3>
                                <p>Masa de papa sancochada, rellena de pollo y más verduras</p>
                            </div>
                            <div class="col der">
                                <p class="precio">S/. 8.50</p>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <!-- Plato 4 -->
                        <div class="item">
                            <div class="col izq">
                                <h3>Ceviche</h3>
                                <p>Comida marina</p>
                            </div>
                            <div class="col der">
                                <p class="precio">S/. 10</p>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <!-- Menú Bebidas -->

                    <div id="bebidas">

                        <!-- Plato 1 -->
                        <div class="item">
                            <div class="col izq">
                                <h3>Inka Cola</h3>
                                <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</p>
                            </div>
                            <div class="col der">
                                <p class="precio">S/. 1.99</p>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <!-- Plato 2 -->
                        <div class="item">
                            <div class="col izq">
                                <h3>Limonada</h3>
                                <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</p>
                            </div>
                            <div class="col der">
                                <p class="precio">S/. 0.80</p>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <!-- Plato 3 -->
                        <div class="item">
                            <div class="col izq">
                                <h3>Chicha Morada</h3>
                                <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</p>
                            </div>
                            <div class="col der">
                                <p class="precio">S/. 1.00</p>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <!-- Plato 4 -->
                        <div class="item">
                            <div class="col izq">
                                <h3>Maracuya</h3>
                                <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</p>
                            </div>
                            <div class="col der">
                                <p class="precio">S/. $0.90</p>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>


                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </section>
```

Mí Javascript:

var propTabs = {

```
primer_encabezado: document.getElementById('encabezado_menu').firstElementChild,
primer_contenido: document.getElementById('contenido_menu').firstElementChild,
enlaces_encabezado: document.querySelectorAll('#encabezado_menu li a'),
li_encabezado: document.querySelectorAll('#encabezado_menu li'),
divs_contenido: document.querySelectorAll('#contenido_menu > div'),
contenido_activo: null
```

}
var metTabs = {

```
inicio: function() {
    propTabs.primer_encabezado.className = 'active';
    propTabs.primer_contenido.className = 'active';

    for (var i = 0; i < propTabs.enlaces_encabezado.length; i++) {
        propTabs.enlaces_encabezado[i].addEventListener('click', metTabs.evento);
    }
},

evento: function(e) {
    e.preventDefault()

    for (var i = 0; i < propTabs.li_encabezado.length; i++) {
        propTabs.li_encabezado[i].className = '';
    }

    for (var i = 0; i < propTabs.divs_contenido.length; i++) {
        propTabs.divs_contenido[i].className = '';
    }

    this.parentElement.className = 'active';
    propTabs.contenido_activo = this.getAttribute('href');
    document.querySelector(propTabs.contenido_activo).className = 'active';
    
}
```

}
metTabs.inicio();

Comment: ¿Responde esto a tu pregunta? [¿Qué significa el error "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set/read property 'XXX' of undefined/null" y cómo solucionarlo?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/169194/qu%c3%a9-significa-el-error-uncaught-typeerror-cannot-set-read-property-xxx-of-u)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solución encontrada:
En el apartado de mi HTML, la href tenía que tener el mismo nombre que el item

```
<li><a href="#comida">Platos</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#bebidas">Bebidas</a></li>
```

Answer (score 0):

El error indica que el elemento no existe o es nulo, y claramente estás definiendo como nulo. Por eso no hay a quien asignar la clase active

Comment: Perdón, me habían indicado de esa manera, para que así el elemento pueda existir. 
Me podría recomendar una propiedad para mi: contenido_activo: ****
Por favor.