# Obtener datos con AJAX para Chart js (Cannot read property 'getContext' of null)

Tags: javascript, jquery, chart.js

Buenas noches estoy intentando traer valores con un selector de año pero no consigo que funcione.

**Mi HTML**

```
<div class="card">
   <div class="form-group">
      <select class="form-control" id="ano" onchange="muestraMas();">
        <option value="2021">2021</option>
        <option value="2020">2020</option>
      </select>
   </div>
   <div id="laGrafica">
      <canvas id="rpuba"></canvas>
   </div>
        
   <div>{{ $porcentaje }}%</div>
</div>
```

**Mi JavaScript**

```
<script>
  let potenciales = '';
  window.onload=muestraMas;
  function muestraMas(){
  var var1=document.getElementById('ano').value;
  var url = '/selectAno';
  console.log(var1);
  $.ajax({
    headers: { 'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content') },
    type: "GET",
    url: url,
    data: {'ano': var1},
          beforeSend: function(){
            $("#laGrafica").html("<div id='loader'></div>")
          },
          success: function (resultado){
            
              potenciales = resultado.potenciales.total
              clientes = resultado.clientes.total
              
              //const $grafica = document.querySelector("#rpuba").getContext('2d');
              var ctx = document.querySelector("#rpuba").getContext('2d');
              var clientes = new Chart(ctx, {
              type: 'doughnut',
              data: {
                  labels: ['Clientes potenciales', 'Clientes finales'],
                  datasets: [
                          {
                            label: 'Dataset 1',
                            data: [potenciales, clientes],
                            backgroundColor: ['#4bc0c0','#37a2eb'],
                            borderColor: "#fff",
                          }
                        ]
              },
              options: {
                responsive: true,
                plugins: {
                  legend: {
                    position: 'top',
                  },
                  title: {
                    display: true,
                    text: 'Conversión de Cliente Potencial a Cliente Final'
                  }
                }
              },

          });
              setTimeout(function(){ $("#laGrafica").html(resultado); }, 1000); 
          },
          error: function(e) { $("#laGrafica").html("Sucedió un error!") }
  });
}

</script>
```

**Y en mi controlador**

```
public function selectAno(Request $request)
    {
        $potenciales = Cliente::select(DB::raw('count(*) as total'))
                    ->whereIn('tipo_cliente', [0])
                    ->whereYear('created_at', '=', $request->ano)
                    ->groupBy('tipo_cliente')->first();
        $clientes = Cliente::select(DB::raw('count(*) as total'))
                    ->whereIn('tipo_cliente', [3])
                    ->whereYear('created_at', '=', $request->ano)
                    ->groupBy('tipo_cliente')->first();   

        return with(['potenciales' => $potenciales, 'clientes' => $clientes]);
    }
```

Pero recibo todo el rato `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'getContext' of null` alguna sugerencia por favor!?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

En tu código tienes esto:

```
beforeSend: function(){
    $("#laGrafica").html("<div id='loader'></div>")
}
```

Que elimina el canvas que originalmente había dentro del div con id `laGrafica`.

Esto hace que no pueda encontrarlo posteriormente: No existe un canvas con id `rpuba`

```
var ctx = document.querySelector("#rpuba").getContext('2d');
```

Te recomiendo mirar [¿Qué significa el error "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set/read property 'XXX' of undefined/null" y cómo solucionarlo?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/169194/qu%c3%a9-significa-el-error-uncaught-typeerror-cannot-set-read-property-xxx-of-u) para entender ese mensaje de error, es habitual encontrárselo y suele ser fácil de corregir una vez averiguas qué lo causa.