# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of null

Tags: javascript, jquery

Buenas noches estoy obteniendo resultado a través de un AJAX, en mi consulta además de comparar datos añado un with para traer una relación.

**Mi consulta**

```
$ciudades = Ubicacion::with('ProvinciaOne')->selectRaw('ciudad, COUNT(ciudad) AS Total')
            ->join('clientes', 'ubicacions.cliente_id', '=', 'clientes.id')
            ->orderBy('Total', 'DESC')
            ->whereYear('clientes.fecha_contacto', '=', $request->ano4)
            ->groupBy('ciudad')->get();
```

**Esto me devuelve esto:**

```
0:
  Total: 65
  ciudad: "46"
  provincia_one:
     capital_id: 7219
     comunidad_id: 10
     created_at: null
     id: 46
     provincia: "Valencia"
     slug: "valencia"
     tarifa: 1
     updated_at: "2021-01-08 10:42:24"
     [[Prototype]]: Object
  [[Prototype]]: Object
```

En mi vista hago una iteración con el resultado:

```
for(i=0;i<resultado.ciudades.length;i++){ 
   console.log(resultado.ciudades);
   html +=
    `<div class="row rowBorder">
       <div class="col-9">
         <h5 class="h5Font">${resultado.ciudades[i].provincia_one.provincia}</h5>
       </div>
       <div class="col-3">
       <div class="pull-right burbujaCount">
         ${resultado.ciudades[i].Total}
       </div>
      </div>
      </div>`
    }
```

Si hago un `console.log(resultado.ciudades[i].provincia_one.provincia)` me devuelve una iteración con todos los nombres de `provincia_one.provincia` pero en cuanto lo pongo aquí: `${resultado.ciudades[i].provincia_one.provincia}` me devuelve este error: `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'provincia')` ¿que estoy haciendo mal?

Haciendo `console.log(resultado.ciudades[i].provincia_one);`

```
{id: 49, slug: 'zamora', provincia: 'Zamora', comunidad_id: 7, capital_id: 7821, …}
  capital_id: 7821
  comunidad_id: 7
  created_at: null
  id: 49
  provincia: "Zamora"
  slug: "zamora"
  tarifa: 2
  updated_at: "2021-05-10 11:59:43"
[[Prototype]]: Object
```

Comment: Has un console.log de resultado.ciudades[i].provincia_one

Comment: Hola @JonathanOrta publique en mi pregunta el resultado de lo que me pides

Comment: ¿Es posible que para algún valor de `i` no exista `resultado.ciudades[i].provincia_one`? Es lo que parece decir el error

Comment: Pues ahora que lo dices si @PabloLozano hay alguno que no está rellenado por falta de información, se puede hacer igual?

Comment: [Pregunta relacionada](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/169194/qu%c3%a9-significa-el-error-uncaught-typeerror-cannot-set-read-property-xxx-of-u). No he votado duplicada porque en este caso el tener una lista de objetos hace el escenario algo más complejo de entender y es una buena oportunidad de presentar los operadores `.?` y `??`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

El error está causando porque alguno de los objetos por los que iteras no tiene toda la información que esperas. La forma más rápida de solucionarlo sería comprobar si ese valor existe o no, que puedes hacer con:

```javascript
    ${resultado.ciudades[i]?.provincia_one?.provincia ?? 'Sin datos'}
```

Explicación:

```js
let obj = {
  dato : {
    a: 'test'
  }
};

console.log(obj); // se muestra el objeto
console.log(obj?.dato?.a); //se muestra el atributo dato.a si dato y dato.a existen
console.log(obj?.dato2?.b); //se muestra el atributo dato2.b si dato2  y dato2.b existen

//se muestra el atributo dato2.b si existe, en otro caso se muestra el string "No hay datos"
console.log(obj?.dato2?.b ?? 'No hay datos');
```

Comment: Brillante @PabloLozano funciona de manera perfecta y he comprendido por que no funcionaba, gracias!

Comment: todo un genio crack