# error javaScript en la versión mobile

Tags: javascript, wordpress

Quiero hacer un ejercicio aparentemente muy simple y que funciona perfectamente en el Visual Studio. Quiero hacer un header dinámico, que cambie de color conforme hago scroll hacia abajo por la pantalla.

```
let cabecera = document.querySelector(".header--row-inner");
//let cabeceraMobile = window.getComputedStyle(document.querySelector('.header--row-inner', '::before'));
//let cabeceraMobile=document.querySelector(".container .row .row--wrapper");

window.onscroll = function() {
    var pos = window.scrollY;
    console.log(pos);

    if(pos > 820){/* .top y .y tienen los mismos valores*/
        cabecera.style.transition = "0.6s";
        cabecera.style.backgroundColor = "rgb(00, 64, 121)";
      
      cabeceraMobile.style.transition = "0.6s";
        cabeceraMobile.style.backgroundColor = "rgb(00, 64, 121)";
    }else{
        cabecera.style.backgroundColor = "rgba(0,0,0,0)";
      cabeceraMobile.style.backgroundColor = "rgba(0,0,0,0)";
    }
```

Como les digo, el código funciona perfectamente en Visual. El problema es en Wordpress, el cual solamente funciona en la versión de escritorio. En mobile no funciona https://www.lipsoft.es/ y no se por qué. He probado crear una nueva variable llamada cabeceraMobile para seleccionar el ::before u otro contenedor pero sigue sin funcionar. Me lanza el mismo error:

[image: Error Cannot read properties of nullintroducir el código aquí]

Comment: Relacionado: https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/169194/qu%c3%a9-significa-el-error-uncaught-typeerror-cannot-set-read-property-xxx-of-u

Comment: La variable cabeceraMobile es null, por tanto no puedes aplicarle un estilo. Investiga por qué cabecera no está presente.