# ¿Por qué no me aparece en la variable medida lo que el usuario escribe en la caja de texto?

Tags: javascript, html

Estoy tratando de hacer una página que calcule el área o perímetro de un círculo, cuadrado o triangulo dependiendo de la elección del usuario, pero me aparece un error que no puedo resolver y es que al parecer al tratar de entrar a la consola del navegador y saber el valor de la variable `medida` después de darle al botón de `click` en el documento, no me aparece lo que el usuario escribió en la caja de texto y no se porque. En la consola del navegador me aparece un error que dice

```
"Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'addEventListener')".
```

Cabe aclarar que me falta hacer el código para calcular el área y el perímetro del triángulo y el círculo, pero aun no lo hago porque primero estoy intentando hacerlo con el cuadrado para posteriormente hacerlo con las demás.

```js
//Codigo del cuadrado

function calcularPerimetroCuadrado(medidaLado){ //funcion para calcular el perimetro del cuadrado
    console.group("Cuadrados");
    perimetroCuadrado = medidaLado * 4;
    console.log("El perimetro del cuadrado es: " + perimetroCuadrado + " cm.");
    r.innerHTML = "El perimetro del cuadrado es: " + perimetroCuadrado;
}

function calcularAreaCuadrado(medidaLado){
    areaCuadrado = medidaLado * medidaLado;
    console.log("El área del cuadrado es: " + areaCuadrado + " cm^2.");
    console.groupEnd();
}



//Codigo del triangulo

function calcularPerimetroTriangulo(lado1, lado2, lado3){
    console.group("Triángulos");
    perimetroTriangulo = lado1 + lado2 + lado3;
    console.log("El perimetro del triángulo es: " + perimetroTriangulo + " cm.");
}

function calcularAreaTriangulo(base, altura){ 
    areaTriangulo = (base * altura)/2;
    console.log("El área del triángulo es: " + areaTriangulo + " cm^2.");
    console.groupEnd();
}


//Codigo del circulo

function diametroCirculo(radio){
    return radio * 2;
}

function calcularPerimetroCirculo(radio){ //funcion para calcular el perimetro del circulo
    console.group("Circulos");
    var diametro = diametroCirculo(radio);
    perimetroCirculo = diametro * PI ;
    console.log("El perimetro (circunferencia) del circulo es: " + perimetroCirculo + " cm.");
}

function calcularAreaCirculo(radio){ //funcion para calcular el area del circulo
    areaCirculo = PI * (radio * radio);
    console.log("El area del circulo es: " + areaCirculo + " cm^2.");
    console.groupEnd();
}

//variables

var perimetroCuadrado;
var areaCuadrado;

var perimetroTriangulo;
var areaTriangulo;

var perimetroCirculo;
var areaCirculo; 

var PI = Math.PI;  //PI

var medida;

var b2;

//Aqui vamos a obtener las etiquetas de HTML 5 para guardarlas en variables

var cu = document.getElementById("cuadrado");;
var t = document.getElementById("triangulo");
var ci = document.getElementById("circulo");

var p = document.getElementById("perimetro");
var a = document.getElementById("area");

var b = document.getElementById("boton");
b.addEventListener("click", calcular);

var e = document.getElementById("escribir");

var r = document.getElementById("respuesta");

b2.addEventListener("click", calcularCuadrado); //evento de click al boton "click".

function calcular(){ 

    if (cu.selected) {
        e.innerHTML = '¿Cuál es la medida del lado del cuadrado <input type = "text" id = "medida" /> <input type = "button" value = "click" id = "calculo"/>';
        b2 = document.getElementById("calculo");
        medida = document.getElementById("medida")
    }

}

function calcularCuadrado(){
    medida = parseInt(medida.value);
    calcularPerimetroCuadrado(medida);
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
  <html>
      <head>
          <meta charset = "utf-8" />
          <title>Figuras Geómetricas | Curso Práctico de Javascript en Platzi</title>
      </head>
      <body>
          <p>
              <h1>Figuras geómetricas</h1>
          </p>

          <p>Para calcular el área o perimetro de las figuras geometricas llena lo que se te pide.</p> 

          <p>
              Figura geométrica:
              <select id="opcionesFigura">
                  <option>...</option>
                  <option value = "Cuadradote" id = "cuadrado" label = "Cuadrado">Cuadrado</option>
                  <option value = "Triangulote" id = "triangulo" label = "Triángulo">Triángulo</option>
                  <option value = "Circulote" id = "circulo" label = "Circulo">Circulo</option>
              </select>
          </p>
          <p>
              ¿Qué quieres calcular?
              <select id="opcionesCalculo">
                  <option>...</option>
                  <option id = "perimetro" label = "Perimetro">Perimetro</option>
                  <option id = "area" label = "Área">Área</option>
              </select>
          </p>
          <p>
              Haz click aquí para calcular
              <input type = "button" value = "Calcular" id = "boton" />
          </p>
          <p id = "escribir"></p>
          <p id = "respuesta"></p>
          <script src = "figuras.js"></script>
      </body>
  </html>
```

Comment: Hola Edson, bienvenido a SOes! El error que te da no está producido por el código expuesto, ¿tienes algo más que no has añadido, pensando que no era relevante? Relacionado: https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/169194/qu%c3%a9-significa-el-error-uncaught-typeerror-cannot-set-read-property-xxx-of-u

Answer (score 0, accepted):

La razón por la que no te trae el valor es porque en ningún momento lo solicitas, debes utilizar un input en lugar de p, para obtener el contenido de un p se puede utilizar textContent, innerHTML o innerText dependiendo de algunas cosas, p no es una etiqueta para ingresar datos, sino para mostrar parrafos.

Hice varias correcciones, dejo ejemplo funcional con cuadrado/area y cuadrado/perimetro:

Archivo HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <title>Document</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <h1>Figuras geómetricas</h1>

    <p>
      Para calcular el área o perimetro de las figuras geometricas llena lo que
      se te pide.
    </p>

    <div>
      Figura geométrica:
      <select id="opcionesFigura" onchange="tipoDeFigura()">
        <option>...</option>
        <option value="Cuadrado" label="Cuadrado">Cuadrado</option>
        <option value="Triangulo" label="Triángulo">Triángulo</option>
        <option value="Circulo" label="Circulo">Circulo</option>
      </select>
    </div>
    <div>
      ¿Qué quieres calcular?
      <select id="opcionesCalculo" onchange="opcionesCalculo()">
        <option>...</option>
        <option value="perimetro" label="Perimetro">Perimetro</option>
        <option value="area" label="Área">Área</option>
      </select>
    </div>

    <div id="escribir"></div>
    <div id="respuesta"></div>
    <script src="app3.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Archivo js:

```
function tipoDeFigura() {
  const figuraSeleccionada = document.getElementById("opcionesFigura").value;
  const escribir = document.getElementById("escribir");
  escribir.innerHTML =
    '¿Cuál es la medida del lado del cuadrado <input type = "text" id = "medida" /> <button type = "button" onclick="ejecutarCalculo()"/>Calcular</button>';
  return figuraSeleccionada;
}

function opcionesCalculo() {
  const opcionCalculo = document.getElementById("opcionesCalculo").value;
  return opcionCalculo;
}

function ejecutarCalculo() {
  const medidaLado = document.getElementById("medida").value;
  if (tipoDeFigura() === "Cuadrado") {
    if (opcionesCalculo() === "area") {
      calcularAreaCuadrado(medidaLado);
    } else {
      calcularPerimetroCuadrado(medidaLado);
    }
  } //Acá agregaríamos un else if con por ejemplo opcionesCalculo() === Triangulo y detro sus if como el cuadrado
}

function calcularPerimetroCuadrado(medidaLado) {
  const r = document.getElementById("respuesta");
  const perimetroCuadrado = medidaLado * 4;
  console.log("El perimetro del cuadrado es: " + perimetroCuadrado + " cm.");
  r.innerHTML = "El perimetro del cuadrado es: " + perimetroCuadrado + " cm.";
}

function calcularAreaCuadrado(medidaLado) {
  const areaCuadrado = medidaLado * medidaLado;
  const r = document.getElementById("respuesta");
  r.innerHTML = "El área del cuadrado es: " + areaCuadrado;
  console.log("El área del cuadrado es: " + areaCuadrado + " cm^2.");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Intenta agregando esto a los `addEventListener`

**Ejemplo:**

```
button.addEventListener("click", ()=>calcularCuadrado());
```

Espero haberte ayudado!