# Mostrar un DropdownList en una vista MVC C# usando Entity Framwork-

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-5, entity-framework

estoy tratando de mostrar un dropdownlist, de una entidad que tengo en mi modelo, para ello eh usado entityframework database first.

Codigo en mi vista:

```
<div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.DropDownListFor(x => x.Nivel.NivelID, new SelectList(Model.ListNivel,"NivelID","Nivel1"), htmlAttributes : new { @class = "form-control" })                   
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(x => x.Nivel.NivelID, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })

            </div>
```

Mi modelo:

```
 public partial class Nivel
{
    [System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Usage", "CA2214:DoNotCallOverridableMethodsInConstructors")]
    public Nivel()
    {
        this.Detalle_Curso = new HashSet<Detalle_Curso>();
        this.Seccion = new HashSet<Seccion>();
    }

    public int NivelID { get; set; }
    public string Nivel1 { get; set; }
    public string Descripcion { get; set; }

    //public List<Nivel> SelectListItems { get; set; }


    [System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Usage", "CA2227:CollectionPropertiesShouldBeReadOnly")]
    public virtual ICollection<Detalle_Curso> Detalle_Curso { get; set; }
    [System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Usage", "CA2227:CollectionPropertiesShouldBeReadOnly")]
    public virtual ICollection<Seccion> Seccion { get; set; }
}
```

Como estoy tratando de referenciar varios modelos en una misma vista, cree una clase para poder referenciarlos.

```
 public class CursoxGrado
{
    public Nivel Nivel {get; set;}
     public List<Nivel> ListNivel { get; set; }

    public Grado Grado {get; set;}

    public Año_Academico Año_Academico { get; set; }

    public Curso Curso { get; set; }
}
```

Justo creo un List de mi entidad, pero cuando ejecuto me manda el siguiente error.
[image: Error que me manda]

Comment: Posible duplicado de [¿Qué es una NullReferenceException y cómo solucionarla?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/75999/qu%c3%a9-es-una-nullreferenceexception-y-c%c3%b3mo-solucionarla)

Comment: A que te refieres con posible duplicado amigo?

Comment: Lee esa pregunta y fijate si no podes solucionar el problema con lo que dice ahi...

Comment: podrias poner el codigo del action del controller ? porque no se observa como es que conviertes la entidad que obtienes desde EF a la clase CursoxGrado que usas en la view