# Acumular variables con checkbox

Tags: c#, windows-forms, checkbox, sms, datagridview

Tengo un **DataGridView** que muestra **nombre, celular** desde una base de datos en SQLServer y que tiene **CheckBoxes**. El botón enviará de manera masiva mensajes a esos clientes, por eso es que quiero que se cada **CheckBox** tildado almacene la variable. El problema está en que no se mandan los mensajes en el **ciclo for** que hice.

Para enviar mensajes de manera masiva se utiliza este bloque en string:

```
string bloque = "";

bloque += bloque + "ID1\tNumeroCelular\tMensaje\n";//cliente A

bloque += bloque + "ID2\tNumeroCelular\tMensaje\n";//cliente B
```

Entonces pensé que podría hacerlo de otra manera haciendo un ciclo, el cual aumentaría el **ID** de manera automática por cada **CheckBox** tildado y asignaría el **celular** al ciclo para que cuando presione el botón este envíe el mensaje a todos los clientes seleccionados.

Actualmente, esto es todo lo que tengo de código:

```
public partial class Form1 : Form {
    int contador = 0;
    public Form1(){
        InitializeComponent();
    }
    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e){
        llenarId();
        //dtgId.ReadOnly = true;
        DataGridViewCheckBoxColumn chk = new DataGridViewCheckBoxColumn();
        chk.HeaderText = "Seleccione";
        chk.Name = "check";
        dtgId.Columns.Add(chk);
        dtgId.AllowUserToAddRows = false;
    }

    public void llenarId(){
        try{
            string cadena = "cadena";
            using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(cadena)){
                con.Open();
                string query = "SELECT id, nombre, celular FROM clientes";
                SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(query, con);
                SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
                DataSet ds = new DataSet();
                da.Fill(ds);
                dtgId.DataSource = ds.Tables[0];
                con.Close();
            }
        }
        catch (SqlException ex){
            MessageBox.Show("Error: " + ex.Message, "Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
        }
    }

    private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e){
        List<string> celulares = new List<string>();
        foreach (DataGridViewRow row in dtgId.Rows){
            bool variable = (bool)row.Cells[3].Value;
            if (variable){
                celulares.Add(row.Cells[2].Value.ToString());//columna donde estan los celulares
            }
        }

        //Codigo para enviar SMS
        string usuario = "usuario";
        string clave = "clave";
        string respuesta = ""; 
        string texto = txtTexto.Text;
        string bloque = "";
        //bloque += bloque + "ID1\tNumeroCelular\tMensaje\n"; trato de reemplazar esto por el ciclo for
        contador++;
        for (int i = 0; i < celulares.Count; i++){
            bloque = bloque + "ID" + Convert.ToInt32(contador) + "\t" + celulares[i] + "\t" + texto + "\n";
            Console.WriteLine(bloque);
        }

        Uri uri = new Uri("uri");

        HttpWebRequest requestFile = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(uri);
        requestFile.Method = "POST";
        requestFile.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
        StringBuilder postData = new StringBuilder();
        postData.Append("api=" + System.Web.HttpUtility.UrlEncode("1") + "&");
        postData.Append("usuario=" + System.Web.HttpUtility.UrlEncode(usuario) + "&");
        postData.Append("clave=" + System.Web.HttpUtility.UrlEncode(clave) + "&");
        postData.Append("separadorcampos=" + System.Web.HttpUtility.UrlEncode("tab") + "&");
        postData.Append("bloque=" + System.Web.HttpUtility.UrlEncode(bloque) + "&");

        //byte[] byteArray = Encoding.GetEncoding("iso-8859-1").GetBytes(postData.ToString());
        byte[] byteArray = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(postData.ToString());

        requestFile.ContentLength = byteArray.Length;

        Stream requestStream = requestFile.GetRequestStream();
        requestStream.Write(byteArray, 0, byteArray.Length);
        requestStream.Close();
        HttpWebResponse webResp = requestFile.GetResponse() as HttpWebResponse;
        if (requestFile.HaveResponse){
            if (webResp.StatusCode == HttpStatusCode.OK || webResp.StatusCode == HttpStatusCode.Accepted){
                StreamReader respReader = new StreamReader(webResp.GetResponseStream(), Encoding.GetEncoding("iso-8859-1"));
                respuesta = respReader.ReadToEnd();
                MessageBox.Show(respuesta);
            }
        }
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {//agregué este botón sin el ciclo para mostrarles que de este modo si funciona
        //Codigo para enviar SMS
        string usuario = "usuario";
        string clave = "clave";
        string bloque = "";
        string respuesta = ""; //en esta variable quedará la respuesta del llamado a la API de SMS MASIVOS

        bloque = bloque + "ID1\t1111111111\tPrueba \n";
        bloque = bloque + "ID2\t2222222222\tPrueba \n";

        Uri uri = new Uri("uri");

        HttpWebRequest requestFile = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(uri);

        requestFile.Method = "POST";
        requestFile.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";

        StringBuilder postData = new StringBuilder();
        postData.Append("api=" + System.Web.HttpUtility.UrlEncode("1") + "&");
        postData.Append("usuario=" + System.Web.HttpUtility.UrlEncode(usuario) + "&");
        postData.Append("clave=" + System.Web.HttpUtility.UrlEncode(clave) + "&");
        postData.Append("separadorcampos=" + System.Web.HttpUtility.UrlEncode("tab") + "&");
        postData.Append("bloque=" + System.Web.HttpUtility.UrlEncode(bloque) + "&");
        byte[] byteArray = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(postData.ToString());

        requestFile.ContentLength = byteArray.Length;

        Stream requestStream = requestFile.GetRequestStream();
        requestStream.Write(byteArray, 0, byteArray.Length);
        requestStream.Close();

        HttpWebResponse webResp = requestFile.GetResponse() as HttpWebResponse;

        if (requestFile.HaveResponse)
        {
            if (webResp.StatusCode == HttpStatusCode.OK || webResp.StatusCode == HttpStatusCode.Accepted)
            {
                StreamReader respReader = new StreamReader(webResp.GetResponseStream(), Encoding.GetEncoding("iso-8859-1"));

                respuesta = respReader.ReadToEnd();
                MessageBox.Show(respuesta);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Cual seria exactamente el problema? porque estas guardando los celulares en una lista...

Comment: Lo que sucede es que aunque los guarde en una lista, no consigo que se envíen varios mensajes al presionar el botón. @gbianchi

Comment: Al presionar que boton? donde esta ese codigo que falla? tomate unos segundos, y escribe la pregunta como para que entendamos tu problema.. asi como esta, es una maraña de codigo y no se entiende que esta pasando y donde...

Comment: Ya lo  he modificado @gbianchi

Comment: Tu codigo esta tirando un error no?

Comment: No, no me está mostrando ningún error @gbianchi

Comment: Y entonces cuando dices que no funciona, que es lo que no funciona?

Comment: Al hecho de que no llegan los mensajes luego de presionar el botón. A eso me refiero con el "no funciona". Si yo utilizo esto: ```bloque += bloque + "ID1\tNumeroCelular\tMensaje\n";``` añadiendo varios de esos bloques con distinto ID y celular los mensaje se envían y me llegan. Pero, al usar el ciclo no envía ni me llegan los mensajes

Comment: Y el string se arma correctamente? o sea el problema es armar el string o enviar los mensajes?

Comment: Sí, el string funciona de manera correcta porque probé añadiendo un TextBox haciendo que al seleccionar un cliente, se escriba el celular en el TextBox y al presionar el botón me llegó el mensaje. El problema es que eso solo funciona con un cliente. Por ende, el problema está en enviar varios mensajes a la vez @gbianchi

Comment: @FranqoBalsamo en el For solo lo estas recorriendo, pero no le estas pasando la posicion del recorrido, por ejemplo celulares[i]

Comment: Ya, lo acabo de añadir y aún no funciona @Manny

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Tu problema no es lo que decis.

Tu problema es que el string que estas armando esta mal.

No es un problema al enviar mensajes.

Fijate este codigo:

```
List<string> celulares = new List<string>();
....
for (int i = 0; i < celulares.Count; i++)
{
    bloque += bloque + "ID" + Convert.ToInt32(contador) + "\t" + celulares + "\t" + texto + "\n";//no funciona
}
```

Si celulares es una lista, que esperas que ponga al concatenar la lista celulares en ese string? pues, pone cualquier cosa, y tu string esta mal formado (por eso te pregunte si tu string estaba bien, y si lo miras, no, no esta bien)...

Lo que necesitas es agregarle cual fila de celulares queres...

Y para eso, como es una lista, y la misma se puede manejar como si fuera un array, alcanza con hacer

```
celulares[i]
```

Entonces, tu linea deberia ser:

```
bloque += bloque + "ID" + Convert.ToInt32(contador) + "\t" + celulares[i] + "\t" + texto + "\n"
```

### Edición

Acabo de detectar otro error.. estas sumando bloque dos veces por cada vuelta! la linea deberia ser

```
bloque += "ID" + Convert.ToInt32(contador) + "\t" + celulares[i] + "\t" + texto + "\n"
```

Comment: Lo acabo de añadir, y no la verdad sigue sin mandar los mensajes.

Comment: Pero miraste que el string este bien? y donde en todo tu codigo se mandan los mensajes?

Comment: Y si escribis a mano funciona? Me parece que mareaste totalmente tu problema... @FranqoBalsamo. Para dos numeros pasados a mano podes?

Comment: Sí, para dos números pasados a mano si funciona. Veamos: 

```bloque += bloque + "ID1\t11111111\tMensaje\n";//cliente A```

```bloque += bloque + "ID2\t2222222\tMensaje\n";//cliente B```

Si yo escribo eso así, manualmente en el código del botón , sí funciona

Comment: Vale, edité el código original para que veas que con string cargado de manera manual dentro de un botón funciona.

Comment: Perfecto, y ahora nos muestras que queda en bloque una vez que pasa el for? para ver si lo esta armando bien, que es lo que te pregunte varias veces ya... @FranqoBalsamo

Comment: @FranqoBalsamo fijate que tenias otro error al armar el string.. sumabas dos veces el string anterior

Comment: Primero, no entiendo bien tu pregunta sobre que queda en bloque una vez que pasa el  for? Ese es todo el código del aplicativo. Y en cuánto al error del string lo puse así porque el código original del bloque es: ```bloque=bloque+etcétera```

Comment: @FranqoBalsamo que queda dentro del string bloque. depura tu programa y fijate si queda un string que sea valido...

Comment: Pues depuro y me sale: `null`

Comment: Y en que momento le asignas null a bloque? si "" no es lo mismo que null y asi es como se inicia? @FranqoBalsamo

Comment: Bien, ya he modificado el código y ahora funciona de manera correcta. No puedo poner `bloque="ID"+etcétera` porque sino no envía los mensajes. Por lo que debo dejarlo como `bloque = bloque +"Id"+etcétera`. Ahora, esto funciona si selecciono todos los checkbox si no selecciono ninguno o si selecciono algunos sale este error: `System.NullReferenceException: 'Referencia a objeto no establecida como instancia de un objeto.' System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewCell.Value.get devolvió null.`

Comment: Eso es otra pregunta distinta. Si modificas asi la pregunta, la respuesta ya no tiene sentido. lo que vos estas haciendo con bloque = no es lo que puse yo en mi respuesta, ni lo que tenias en tu codigo. Revisa bien mi edicion, = no es lo mismo que +=. Volve tu pregunta a como estaba, y eso que vos ves esta en el sitio ya contestado, asi que no vale como pregunta. mira https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/75999/qu%c3%a9-es-una-nullreferenceexception-y-c%c3%b3mo-solucionarla @FranqoBalsamo

Answer (score -2):

Lo que debes hacer es añadir un escucha de evento a los las cajas de chequeo  tal que al cambiar de estado puedas eliminar o añadir a la lista donde guardas los números seleccionados para enviar el mensaje

Comment: Estimado, eso es mas un comentario que una respuesta, para responder por favor lee [cómo responder](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) para que tu respuesta sea bien aceptada. Saludos!