# Error al agregar o sustituir tabla de word con C#

Tags: c#

[image: Programa Run]

> Error:System.NullReferenceException: 'Object reference not set to an
> instance of an object.'

Codigo

```
if (dataGridView1.Rows.Count > 0)
{
     object objMiss = System.Reflection.Missing.Value;
     Word.Application ObjWord = new Word.Application();
     string ruta = Application.StartupPath + 
C:\Users\Jonathan\Documents\Proyectos Jonathan\Inventario\Inventario\Reglamento.docx";
     object parametro = ruta;
     object objEndOfDocFlag = "Equipos";
     Word.Document Objdoc = ObjWord.Documents.Open(parametro, objMiss);
     Word.Range objWordRng = Objdoc.Bookmarks.get_Item(ref objEndOfDocFlag).Range;
            
     int NumCols = 10;
     Word.Table objTab1 = Objdoc.Tables.Add(objWordRng, dataGridView1.Rows.Count, NumCols, ref objMiss, ref objMiss);
     objTab1.Range.ParagraphFormat.SpaceAfter = 6;
     int iRow, iCols;
     for (iRow = 1; iRow <= dataGridView1.Rows.Count; iRow++)
     {
          for (iCols = 1; iCols <= NumCols; iCols++)
          {
                 objTab1.Cell(iRow, iCols).Range.Text = dataGridView1.Rows[iRow].Cells[iCols].ToString(); //add some text to cell
          }
     }
}
```

Comment: Revisa [¿Qué es una NullReferenceException y cómo solucionarla?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/75999/15301)

Answer (score 0):

Ya pude solucionar ese problema, todo gracias al comentario que dejaron, muchas gracias, sin embargo tengo otro problema con el mismo codigo, tendria que realizar otra respuesta?

Respuesta: En la variable de Ruta, esta buscando automaticamente en la carpeta Debug por ese motivo me daba error ya que la ruta completa era la carpeta debug mas C:\Users\Jonathan\Documents\Proyectos Jonathan\Inventario\Inventario\Reglamento.docx, cosa que no existia en mi equipo de computo, Saludos!! Simplemente dentro de Debug cree el documento Reglamento y deje de la siguiente manera

object parametro = Application.StartupPath + @"\Reglamento.docx";