# Inconveniente para enviar un dato de una pagina a otra en C# Asp.Net

Tags: c#, asp.net

Cordial saludo, espero se encuentren bien agradezco su colaboración con el siguiente inconveniente que se me presenta referente a enviar un registro de Aspx.net C# a otro dentro de la misma página:

tengo el siguiente inconveniente al momento de seleccionar un registro de una grilla en C# Asp.Net de una grilla a otra:

El código de la grilla en donde tengo el elemento a seleccionar Código_alumno es el siguiente:

```
<asp:GridView ID="GridView1" autogeneratecolumns="false" runat="server" Width="907px" style="margin-left: 4px" OnSelectedIndexChanged="GridView1_SelectedIndexChanged1"> 
<Columns>
<asp:TemplateField HeaderText = "Código_alumno" >
 <ItemTemplate>
 <asp:LinkButton ID="lnkView1" runat="server" CommandArgument='<% # Bind("codalumno") %>' OnClick="lnk1_Onclick" CommandName="Select" > <%# Eval("codalumno") %> </asp:LinkButton>
</ItemTemplate>
</asp:TemplateField>
                   
<asp:BoundField DataField="nombreal"  HeaderText="Nombre_alumno" />
<asp:BoundField DataField="apellal"  HeaderText="Apellido_alumno" />
<asp:BoundField DataField="sexal"  HeaderText="Sexo_alumno" />  
<asp:BoundField DataField="edadal"  HeaderText="Edad_alumno" />  
<asp:BoundField DataField="fechnalal"  HeaderText="Fecha_alumno" />
<asp:BoundField DataField="paisal"  HeaderText="Pais_alumno" />  
<asp:BoundField DataField="correoalu"  HeaderText="Correo_alumno" />
<asp:BoundField DataField="passwalu"  HeaderText="Password_alumno" />
<asp:BoundField DataField="telefalu"  HeaderText="Telefono_alumno" />  
<asp:BoundField DataField="direalu" HeaderText="Direccion_alumno" />   
               
<asp:TemplateField HeaderText = "Visualizar">
 <ItemTemplate>
  <asp:LinkButton ID="LinkButton1" runat="server" CommandArgument='<%# Bind("codalumno") %>' OnClick="lnk_Onclick" CommandName="Select">Ver modo de estado </asp:LinkButton>
 <asp:LinkButton ID="lnkView" runat="server" CommandArgument='<%# Bind("codalumno") %>' OnClick="lnk_Onclick" CommandName="Select">Ver modo de estado </asp:LinkButton>
</ItemTemplate>
</asp:TemplateField>
</Columns>      
</asp:GridView>            


 public void lnk1_Onclick(object sender, EventArgs e) // protected
  {  
          string codalumno1 = ((sender as LinkButton).CommandArgument);
          Response.Redirect("NotasAlumnos.aspx?codalumno1=" + codalumno1,false);
 }
```

Al dar clic sobre el enlace me muestra el siguiente error:

```
GridView1.DataSource = dt; 
GridView1.DataBind();
```

El segmento de código en donde se encuentra el error es el siguiente:

```
public void GetEmployeeList()
{
    
         SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand("Select * from alumnos", connection);
         SqlDataAdapter sd = new SqlDataAdapter(command);
         DataTable dt = new DataTable();
         sd.Fill(dt);
         GridView1.DataSource = dt;
         GridView1.DataBind();
}
```

En el siguiente enlace se muestra la descripción mediante video del inconveniente que se me presenta:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=n5nJvzHrbxw&t=101s

Gracias por su colaboración

Att. Hernán Martínez.

Comment: El error debe estar aqui, no hay porque ir a buscarlo y rastrearlo en un video de youtube...

Comment: En donde esta el error señor Bianchi?

Comment: El error que decis que tiene tu codigo (el problema) debe estar descripto aqui... en la pregunta...

Comment: Ah Ok, de acuerdo muchas gracias por la observación, el error es el siguiente es mas lo voy a incluir editando la solicitud de ayuda, pero te comento el error es el siguiente: Error de servidor en la aplicación '/'.
Referencia a objeto no establecida como instancia de un objeto y me señala la linea de código: this.GridView1.DataSource = (dt); sucede lo mismo si pongo  GridView1.DataSource = dt; me señala la misma linea de codigo, en otras palabras me marca error antes de  GridView1.DataBind(); .                                                 
un abrazo desde Bogotá

Comment: Ese error ya tiene solucion [aqui](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/75999/qu%c3%a9-es-una-nullreferenceexception-y-c%c3%b3mo-solucionarla)