# Error en Unity, NullReferenceException

Tags: c#, unity, unity3d, unity2d

Estoy trabajando en un juego de trivia, llegado el momento de llenar los campos tanto de la pregunta como de los botones con la respuesta, a la hora de compilar y ejecutar tengo el siguiente error: NullReferenceException: Object reference set to an instance of an object.

```
 using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;

public class QuestionDisplay : MonoBehaviour
{
    public GameObject screenQuestion;
    public GameObject answerA;
    public GameObject answerB;
    public GameObject answerC;
    public GameObject answerD;
    void Start()
    {
        screenQuestion.GetComponent<Text>().text = "Cuantas copas del mundo tiene España?";
        answerA.GetComponent<Text>().text = "3";
        answerB.GetComponent<Text>().text = "4";
        answerC.GetComponent<Text>().text = "2";
        answerD.GetComponent<Text>().text = "0";

    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
        
    }
}
```

Esto crea variables publicas a la cual después les asigno el texto que va en cada botón, pero no funciona y no se que hacer, soy nuevo en unity y estoy aprendiendo

Comment: ¿Responde esto a tu pregunta? [¿Qué es una NullReferenceException y cómo solucionarla?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/75999/qu%c3%a9-es-una-nullreferenceexception-y-c%c3%b3mo-solucionarla) Ese es un problema de C# que no se limita a Unity. Es posible que `screenQuestion` , `answerA`, `answerB`, `answerC` o `answerD` sea `null`. Así también que alguna de las llamadas a `GetComponent` retorne `null`.

Comment: Sugiero que cambies los tipos de las variables de `GameObject` a `Text`. Así no tendrás que llamar a `GetComponent` y te simplificas la vida.

Comment: No estás inicializando ningún atributo, tan solo los estás declarando. Deberías inicializarlos llamando al constructor con new o buscando el objeto en tu escena si fuera el caso.