# Mensaje de error al crear un datacontext multiple con WPF

Tags: c#, wpf

estoy tratando de crear un datacontext múltiple. Para esto estoy usando cómo guia el ejemplo que sale en este enlace [Ejemplo](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/679933/wpf-binding-multiple-controls-to-different-datacontexts).
Mi código es el siguiente:

````
public class clEmpleadoVentas
{
   public clDatosEmpleadoH clDatosEmpleadoH { get; set; }
   public clRecorridoEmpleadoH clRecorridoEmpleadoH { get; set; }
   public clDatosVehiculo clDatosVehiculo { get; set; }
   public clEmpleadoVentas()
   {
       clDatosEmpleadoH = new clDatosEmpleadoH();
       clRecorridoEmpleadoH = new clRecorridoEmpleadoH();
       clDatosVehiculo = new clDatosVehiculo();
   }
}

public class clDatosEmpleadoH
    {
        private String _empleadoIDI;
        public String EmpleadoIDI
        {
            get { return _empleadoIDI; }
            set { _empleadoIDI = value; }
        }

        private String _empleadoNombresI;
        public String EmpleadoNombresI
        {
            get { return _empleadoNombresI; }
            set { _empleadoNombresI = value; }
        }

        private String _empleadoTelefonoI;
        public String EmpleadoTelefonoI
        {
            get { return _empleadoTelefonoI; }
            set { _empleadoTelefonoI = value; }
        }

    }

    public class clRecorridoEmpleadoH
    {
        private int _noRecorrido;
        public int NoRecorrido
        {
            get { return _noRecorrido; }
            set { _noRecorrido = value; }
        }

        private String _nombreRecorrido;
        public String NombreRecorrido
        {
            get { return _nombreRecorrido; }
            set { _nombreRecorrido = value; }
        }

        private String _nombreContacto;
        public String NombreContacto
        {
            get { return _nombreContacto; }
            set { _nombreContacto = value; }
        }
    }

    public class clDatosVehiculo
    {
        private String _noPlaca;
        public String NoPlaca
        {
            get { return _noPlaca; }
            set { _noPlaca = value; }
        }

        private String _marcaVehiculo;
        public String MarcaVehiculo
        {
            get { return _marcaVehiculo; }
            set { _marcaVehiculo = value; }
        }

        private Byte _noRuedas;
        public Byte NoRuedas
        {
            get { return _noRuedas; }
            set { _noRuedas = value; }
        }
    }
}

En el xaml de la ventana 
<TextBox x:Name="txtNombresD" Text="{Binding dcMultiple.clDatosEmpleadoH.EmpleadoIDI, Mode=TwoWay}"/> ```
````

En la parte que corresponde a mi code behind:

```
public partial class wVentasEmpleado : Window
{
    clEmpleadoVentas dcMultiple = new clEmpleadoVentas();
    public wVentasEmpleado()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        DataContext = dcMultiple;
    }
    private void Window_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
      dcMultiple.clDatosEmpleadoH.EmpleadoIDI = "T4587";
    }

}
```

El único lugar donde hago referencia y declaro el DataContext es en code behind. Como prueba, al ejecutar la aplicación, ingreso el texto en la variable, pero no aparece el texto en la pantalla. Yo se que de alguna forma es problema con el DataContext, pero hay tantas indicciones diferentes y ya las he probado, pero sigue sin mostrar nada.

¿Alguien me podría explicar donde está mi error? Por favor, necesito resolver esto y es primera ves probando con un datacontext multiple y hay poca literatura sobre esto.
De antemano, gracias.

Comment: Tienes que hacer un New del objeto, sino no existe instancia y salta ese error: `dcMultiple = new clEmpleadoVentas();` Basicamente este error ocurre porque estas intentando asignar un valor a un objeto NULL.

Comment: ¿Responde esto a tu pregunta? [¿Qué es una NullReferenceException y cómo solucionarla?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/75999/qu%c3%a9-es-una-nullreferenceexception-y-c%c3%b3mo-solucionarla)

Comment: Definitivamente, mi problema es cuando trato de hacer un Datacontext multiple como en los ejemplos que he indicado. Si alguien pudiera mostrarme cómo se realiza estas declaraciones con un pequeño ejemplo, les agradecería mucho. Definitivamente no encuentro un ejemplo completo, sólo consejos sin códigos de ejemplo. Gracias a todos, espero su apoyo.

Comment: Edita tu pregunta y no agregues comentarios a ti mismo.

Comment: Ya, listo, la pregunta ya la edité. Saludos Ramiro Barone.