# System null reference exception- Proyecto ASP.net

Tags: c#, asp.net

Estoy iniciando en la programacion con C# y estoy estancada con esta excepcion en un proyecto ASP bastante simple para practica.
Preciso que al clickear en el boton aceptar se agregue todo lo indicado en las cajas de texto y se muestre en la grilla pero me sale esta excepcion. Alguien podria indicarme donde esta el error porque no logro visualizarlo.
Desde ya, muchas gracias y espero poder ayudar a la comunidad mas adelante.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: ¿Responde esto a tu pregunta? [¿Qué es una NullReferenceException y cómo solucionarla?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/75999/qu%c3%a9-es-una-nullreferenceexception-y-c%c3%b3mo-solucionarla)

Comment: Tu problema parece ser que en esa linea la variable de sesion "listaTurnos" por cualquier razón no está aún definida. Este es el significado de la NullReferenceException. Pudieras confirmarlo separando el casting y el "Add" a la lista y debugueando.

Comment: Adicional, como norma general no deberias utilizar la sesion para almacenar estado volatil de la aplicacion. En este caso por ejemplo podrias tener un usuario creando turnos en tu aplicacion y los otros usuarios no lo podrian ver debido a que estan consumiendo un dato "local" que guardaste en su sesion.

Comment: Saludos. Inicializa la variable de sesión (`Session["listaTurno"]`) con el tipo de dato que corresponda, para usarla obtén su valor con una conversión explícita en otra variable local, manipulas esta variable local y al finalizar el proceso la vuelves a asignar a la variable de sesión.

Comment: Muchas gracias a ambos. Pude resolverlo pero no termino de entender bien el proceso. @RobertoLeOr podrias indicarme si estoy asociando correctamente? Inicialice la variable de la sesión con un tipo de dato lista (  List<Turnos> listaTurnos = new List<Turnos>(); ) en el pageload de la pagina default . Para poder usarla realizo el casteo explicito en otra variable local, que seria la variable  denominada "temporal" y la utilizo para poder agregar mi objeto turnos nuevo ?

Answer (score 0):

Como bien mencionas en el `Page_Load` (es por lo regular) donde debes revisar el estado de la variable de sesión; en tu caso `Session["listaTurno"]` para asegurarte esté inicializada y disponible.

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e) {
   // Inicialización de la variable en caso de no existir
   if (Session["listaTurno"]==null)
      Session["listaTurno"] = new List<Turnos>(); 
   // Desde luego lo demás que requieras; sea antes o después de la comprobación e inicialización anterior.
}
```

Con lo anterior ya tienes disponible (que no sea `null`); por tanto en cualquier otra parte del es de la siguiente forma:

```
protected void btnAceptar_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) {
   List<Turnos>() varLocal = (List<Turnos>()) Session["listaTurno"]; // "nunca" será null
   varLocal.add(..lo que quieras agregar..);
   // Puede ser cualquiera de las operaciones.
   // Finalmente actualizas la variable de sesión
   Session["listaTurno"] = varLocal;
}
```

En algún momento intenté hacerlo directamente en la variable de sesión pero no funciono; así que de hace tiempo a hoy, así es como lo realizo.