# Error al ejecutar un programa unity

Tags: unity2d

Al hacer un juego con unity + fungus me da este erorr: NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object
Fungus.DialogInput.Update () (at Assets/Fungus/Scripts/Components/DialogInput.cs:89)

Como lo puedo solucionar?

Comment: ¿Responde esto a tu pregunta? [¿Qué es una NullReferenceException y cómo solucionarla?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/75999/qu%c3%a9-es-una-nullreferenceexception-y-c%c3%b3mo-solucionarla)