# Excepción pdfwriter en iTextSharp

Tags: c#, visual-studio, itextsharp

Tengo un problema, estoy tratando de hacer un pdf con itextsharp pero me está dando el siguiente error:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

*Edit: Les dejo el error escrito.

System.NullReferenceException: 'Referencia a objeto no establecida como instancia de un objeto.'

Les dejo aquí debajo el código que estoy usando:

```
SaveFileDialog guardar = new SaveFileDialog();
        guardar.FileName = DateTime.Today.ToString("ddMMyyyyHHmmss") + ".pdf";

        if(guardar.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
        {

            using(FileStream stream = new FileStream(guardar.FileName, FileMode.Create))
            {
                Document pdfDoc = new Document(PageSize.A4, 25, 25, 25, 25);

                PdfWriter writer = PdfWriter.GetInstance(pdfDoc, stream);

                pdfDoc.Open();
                using (StringReader sr = new StringReader(Contrato()))
                {
                    XMLWorkerHelper.GetInstance().ParseXHtml(writer, pdfDoc, sr);
                }

                pdfDoc.Close();
                stream.Close();
            }


        }
```

Este código lo he basado en varios tutoriales que he visto y a todos les parece funcionar, no sé si el problema proviene de que me está faltando agregar algo al código, una referencia o algo.

*Añado que dentro del FileStream me aparece lo siguiente:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

*Error 1: stream.ReadTimeout
*Error 2: stream.WriteTimeout

No sé si tenga algo que ver y cómo podría solucionarlo en caso de que sea así.

Comment: ¿Cuál es el error? Recuerda que [no todos pueden ver las imágenes](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/3976). Lee [ask] y haz el [tour] para conocer el funcionamiento del sitio. Pulsa en [edit] para agregar más detalles a tu pregunta.

Comment: ¿Responde esto a tu pregunta? [¿Qué es una NullReferenceException y cómo solucionarla?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/75999/qu%c3%a9-es-una-nullreferenceexception-y-c%c3%b3mo-solucionarla)

Comment: ¿Puedes depurar el código o imprimir `pdfDoc` y `stream` para ver cuál es **null**?

Comment: Parece provenir del stream ya que el pdfDoc no me aparece como nulo.